# Making TextView scrollable on Android

Tags: android, scroll, textview, android-scrollview, scrollable

I am displaying text in a TextView that appears to be too long to fit
into one screen. I need to make my TextView scrollable. How can I do
that?

Here is the code:

```
final TextView tv = new TextView(this);
tv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.splash);
tv.setTypeface(face);
tv.setTextSize(18);
tv.setTextColor(R.color.BROWN);
tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL| Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
tv.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {
        Random r = new Random();
        int i = r.nextInt(101);
        if (e.getAction() == e.ACTION_DOWN) {
            tv.setText(tips[i]);
            tv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.inner);
        }
        return true;
    }
});
setContentView(tv);
```

Answer (score 2008, accepted):

You don't need to use a `ScrollView` actually.

Just set the

```
android:scrollbars = "vertical"
```

properties of your `TextView` in your layout's xml file.

Then use:

`yourTextView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());`

in your code.

Bingo, it scrolls!

Comment: But surely `maxLines` requires you to enter an arbitrary number; this isn't something that will work for every screen size and font size? I find it simpler to just wrap it with a `ScrollView`, meaning I don't have to add any further XML attributes or code (like setting the movement method).

Comment: @Christopher, ScrollView requires 'android:layout_height' too.

Comment: @Regex: Well yes. Either you let the `ScrollView` take up as much space as it needs (e.g. via the `android:fillViewport` attribute), or you set the specific size you want. Using `maxLines` should not be used to set sizes of UI elements, so that is no solution.

Comment: Hello. For me this is not a solution (as I thought it is). I have to create all the layout programatically here and when using just a TextView with ScrollMovementMethod(), it scrolls like a 3 px/scroll and very jerky. This TextView is in LineraLayout which is within a ScrollView. When I try to surround thhis TextView with another ScrollView - how can I set the height for it??? Remember - I'm not using any XML here...and ScrollView does not have a `.setHeight()` method. Any suggestion?

Comment: you dont need to define maxlines. just the rest.

Comment: You don't even have to do the TextView.setMovementMethod(..) stuff ;), setting android:scrollbars is actually enough.

Comment: @ubuntudroid it is necessary to add this method. If your text is larger then  the textview if will not scroll.

Comment: @Sunny Well in my experience it does without any problems. Tried on stock Android 2.3.6. May depend on the Android version though.

Comment: This solution didn't Scroll scrolls automatically for me.
i get the scroll with tap/click but that didnt scroll automatically.
how to make it scroll automatically just like vertical mrquee.

Comment: @Christopher: Setting `android:maxLines` isn't necessary.

Comment: thanks thats really worked, and I have used it without mentioning "maxLines", but in my case I has to put yourTextView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod()), without it, in my case not worked.

Comment: It seems like to you have to surround the `TextView` with a `ScrollView` for it to scroll smoothly.

Comment: I found out that [LinkMovementMethod](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/method/LinkMovementMethod.html) already "traverses links in the text buffer and scrolls if necessary."

Thanks for the idea about maxLines and scrollBars. I spent hours figuring about this, and this saved me from wasting more time!

Comment: I found a way to do this without XML.  I've posted it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19649334/how-to-show-scrollbars-on-a-textview-programmatically/19649335#19649335

Comment: I don't know what you all are talking about, I have to actually scroll manually to see the text.
My idea of auto-scrolling is a TextView  that scrolls back and forth without user intervention. Anybody any Idea please?

Comment: This is actually the best and the easiest answer for this :)
This is the equivalent programmatically:

text.setMaxLines(4);      text.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
      text.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);
      text.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);

text.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

Comment: Where is "Smoothness" of scroll?

Comment: doesn't need to set max-lines

Comment: scrolling is not smooth. how to achieve that?

Comment: To clarify what everyone is saying about "smooth" scrolling: If you use this method scrolling is actually "smooth" (in that you can scroll pixel by pixel), however it is *not* kinetic. As soon as you remove your finger it stops scrolling instantly - there is no flicking. This is pretty unacceptable for a modern UI so I'm going to edit the answer to make sure other people don't waste time on this "solution".

Comment: @Timmmm the answer has been accepted 804 times already. So the behavior is acceptable to most devs. And nowhere in the question and answer there is mention of kinetic scrolling. You should not edit an answer just because it does not fulfil your requirements. I think a comment that you made is good enough.

Comment: Kinetic scrolling is an implicit requirement. And I edited the question because you have to scroll down through many ambiguously-worded comments to find out that it doesn't support kinetic scrolling. Shadyyx, Matt Logan, Pratik Butani, Deb, Nishit Shah and Simas have all noted that this doesn't work without issues - I'm sure they would have appreciated my edit. Someone Somewhere's answer is the best (and it has many upvotes) but for some reason is way way down the page).

Comment: Scroller of TextView is not that much fast as it is in ScrollView. I tried this solution and then shifted to the solution of @Someone Somewhere.

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1748977/making-textview-scrollable-on-android/37638516#37638516 maxlines is not needed.

Comment: Once I put my `TextView` in a `FrameView` I couldn't work out why it stopped working, it looks a dirty hack but `TextView.setMovementMethod(..)` is totally necessary.

Comment: whenever you need to use the ScrollView as parent, And you also use the scroll movement method with TextView.

And When you portrait to landscape your device that time occur some issue. (like) entire page is scrollable but scroll movement method can't work.

if you still need to use ScrollView as parent or scroll movement method then click on link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1748977/making-textview-scrollable-on-android/51306133#51306133

Comment: I just tried this on an API 29 emulator, and my `TextView` wouldn't scroll without wrapping it in a `ScrollView`.

Comment: If you have declared and instantiated the TextView progamattically there is no xml file to add 'android:scrollbars = "vertical"' to. How do you do that part programmatically? It appears to work anyway without it, but having hard time using actions to get scrollbars to always show without null object reference error doing it all programatically.

Comment: it's not working in dialogs with wrap height parent, only `ScrollView` will work

Answer (score 341):

This is how I did it purely in XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/SCROLLER_ID"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TEXT_STATUS_ID"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"/>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

**NOTES:**

1. `android:fillViewport="true"` combined with `android:layout_weight="1.0"` will make the textview take up all available space.
2. When defining the Scrollview, DO NOT specify `android:layout_height="fill_parent"` otherwise the scrollview doesn't work! (this has caused me to waste an hour just now! FFS).

**PRO TIP:**

To programmatically scroll to the bottom after appending text, use this:

```
mTextStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TEXT_STATUS_ID);
mScrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.SCROLLER_ID);

private void scrollToBottom()
{
    mScrollView.post(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            mScrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, mTextStatus.getBottom());
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: There's no need to use `mTextView.getBottom()`, just use the method `mScrollView.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN)` as it is a part of the ScrollView API. See [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html#fullScroll%28int%29) and [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#FOCUS_DOWN) for more info.

Comment: Android warns that either the `LinearLayout` or the `ScrollView` may be useless in this example (I removed the `LinearLayout` completely). It also warns that for the `TextView`, it should be `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` to match the `ScrollView`. These warnings may be due to the 3 years that have passed since this answer was posted. Regardless, this answer supports smooth scrolling and flicking...+1

Comment: Adding `<!--suppress AndroidLintUselessParent -->` above the `ScrollView` in the xml file will take care of those warnings.

Comment: The "pro tip" doesn't work for me, in Android API level 9. The textview stays scrolled to the top after appending text.

Comment: This approach is much better using the accepted answer approach will not produce a smooth user experience.

Comment: This didn't work for me. I am receiving the following warning as well: `Invalid layout param in a ScrollView: layout_weight`

Answer (score 120):

All that is really necessary is the setMovementMethod(). Here's an example using a LinearLayout.

## File *main.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:text="@string/hello"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

## File *WordExtractTest.java*

```
public class WordExtractTest extends Activity {

    TextView tv1;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1);

        loadDoc();
    }

    private void loadDoc() {

        String s = "";

        for(int x=0; x<=100; x++) {
            s += "Line: " + String.valueOf(x) + "\n";
        }

        tv1.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

        tv1.setText(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to set this property in XML? I wonder why they would leave out that option.

Comment: It works but Is der any way to refresh it after scrolling? i mean after scrolling the TextView i am going to change text on it, but its position remains scrolled even if it is not required. its bcose previously i had applied scroll...

Comment: no scroll bars, and scrolling is clunky compared to the `ScrollView` method.

Comment: Use a `StringBuilder` instead of a `String`... what you have is a little wasteful.

Comment: @JeffreyBlattman actually, you can get scrollbars by adding `android:scrollbars="vertical"` to the `TextView` XML.

Comment: It really works, but when it is in listview item, does not work!

Comment: this works but the scrolling is not smooth. Still works though thanks.

Answer (score 51):

Make your textview just adding this

```
TextView textview= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.your_textview_id);
textview.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

Comment: This does not do kinetic scrolling. Do not use this.

Comment: @Timmmm how to get the kinetic scroll?

Comment: You don't want "kinetic scrolling" for a text that has to be read.

Comment: @TheincredibleJan yes, you sometimes do

Answer (score 47):

It is not necessary to put in

```
android:Maxlines="AN_INTEGER"`
```

You can do your work by simply adding:

```
android:scrollbars = "vertical"
```

And, put this code in your Java class:

```
textview.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

Comment: Much better solution than the accepted one, as the scrollbar size exactly fits the text and you don't waste space.

Comment: when i am using ScrollView as parent, that time its not working

Comment: i wonder if the textview is vertically loong... just like the discussion here. But what if we want to focus (display) to the specific location of the text located at ...?
is it available just like in html with ID #anchoring...? in android... textview is that possible? @AhsanRaza

Answer (score 29):

You can either

1. surround the `TextView` by a `ScrollView`; or
2. set the Movement method to `ScrollingMovementMethod.getInstance();`.

Answer (score 29):

The best way I found:

Replace the TextView with an EditText with these extra attributes:

```
android:background="@null"
android:editable="false"
android:cursorVisible="false"
```

There is no need for wrapping in a ScrollView.

Comment: Easily the best and most appropriate answer, especially considering that EditText is a TextView subclass and the question is how to make the textview scrollable, not how to work around the problem. Would vote up twice if I could :)

Comment: @JustinBuser Couldn't disagree more. :) It's purely serendipitous that this works, and there's no guarantee it will in future versions of Android.  If you want scrolling, use the scrolling tools that Android provides.  `ScrollView` is the correct way to go.

Comment: @Madbreaks There is nothing "serendipitous" about it, EditText IS a TextView with a few added methods and overrides that is specifically tailored to accommodate varying length text. In particular EditText overrides the return value for the TextView getDefaultMovementMethod function. The default implementation returns NULL, EditText basically does the same thing all these other answers are suggesting.  As far as using the tools that Android provides is concerned, the EditText class is far less likely to become deprecated than any of the other methods found in these answers.

Comment: @JustinBuser My problem with that though is you're depending on the default behavior of EditText, *that* is what I meant may very well change down the road (not at all that EditText would be deprecated). You can argue that, but again, the idea is to use components and features that are appropriate for the task at hand.  ScrollView was explicitly designed to encompass scrolling. I always try to, and always suggest others use the right tool for the job.  There are almost always multiple approaches to any given programming problem.  Anyway, thanks for the thoughtful response.

Comment: 9 years later still working, so I guess the scenarios in the comments didn't happen (yet)

Comment: @Alberto 9 and a half years later and android:editable='false' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. So i will not use this answer.

Comment: @Lothar, you can use inputType="none"

Answer (score 21):

Simple. This is how I did it:

1. XML Side:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
       android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
       tools:context="com.mbh.usbcom.MainActivity">
       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/tv_log"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:scrollbars="vertical"
           android:text="Log:" />
   </RelativeLayout>
   ```
2. Java side:

   ```
   tv_log = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_log);
   tv_log.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
   ```

#### Bonus:

To let the text view scroll down as the text fill it, you have to add:

```
    android:gravity="bottom"
```

to the TextView xml file. It will scroll down automatically as more text comes in.

Of course you need to add the text using the append function instead of set text:

```
    tv_log.append("\n" + text);
```

I used it for Log purpose.

I hope this helps ;)

Answer (score 16):

If you use **Kotlin** , in this way :
**XML**

```
 <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvMore"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLines="3"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />
```

**Activity**

```
tvMore.movementMethod = ScrollingMovementMethod()
```

Comment: This makes fling scroll impossible. In case the text is very large, scrolling is a pain

Answer (score 15):

This is "How to apply ScrollBar to your TextView", using only XML.

First, you need to take a Textview control in the *main.xml* file and write some text into it ... like this:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TEXT"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/long_text"/>
```

Next, place the text view control in between the scrollview to display the scroll bar for this text:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
        android:layout_height="150px"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TEXT"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/long_text"/>

    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

That's it...

Comment: Why even write this? This is an almost identical, albeit less correct, version of an answer that was posted over 6 months before you wrote it.

Answer (score 11):

This will provide smooth scrolling text with a scroll bar.

```
ScrollView scroller = new ScrollView(this);
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
tv.setText(R.string.my_text);
scroller.addView(tv);
```

Comment: Enables blue animation. Best answer here IMO.

Answer (score 11):

The "pro tip" above from Someone Somewhere ([Making TextView scrollable on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1748977/making-textview-scrollable-in-android/8532016#8532016)) works great, however, what if you're dynamically adding text to the ScrollView and would like to automatically scroll to the bottom after an append *only* when the user is at the bottom of the ScrollView? (Perhaps because if the user has scrolled up to read something you don't want to automatically reset to the bottom during an append, which would be annoying.)

Anyway, here it is:

```
if ((mTextStatus.getMeasuredHeight() - mScrollView.getScrollY()) <=
        (mScrollView.getHeight() + mTextStatus.getLineHeight())) {
    scrollToBottom();
}
```

The mTextStatus.getLineHeight() will make it so that you don't scrollToBottom() if the user is within one line from the end of the ScrollView.

Answer (score 11):

In kotlin for making the textview scrollable

```
myTextView.movementMethod= ScrollingMovementMethod()
```

and also add in xml this property

```
    android:scrollbars = "vertical"
```

Answer (score 10):

If you want text to be scrolled within the textview, then you can follow the following:

First you should have to subclass textview.

And then use that.

Following is an example of a subclassed textview.

```
public class AutoScrollableTextView extends TextView {

    public AutoScrollableTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        setEllipsize(TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
        setMarqueeRepeatLimit(-1);
        setSingleLine();
        setHorizontallyScrolling(true);
    }

    public AutoScrollableTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setEllipsize(TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
        setMarqueeRepeatLimit(-1);
        setSingleLine();
        setHorizontallyScrolling(true);
    }

    public AutoScrollableTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setEllipsize(TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
        setMarqueeRepeatLimit(-1);
        setSingleLine();
        setHorizontallyScrolling(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFocusChanged(boolean focused, int direction, Rect previouslyFocusedRect) {
        if(focused)
            super.onFocusChanged(focused, direction, previouslyFocusedRect);
    }

    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean focused) {
        if(focused)
            super.onWindowFocusChanged(focused);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isFocused() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Now, you have to use that in the XML in this way:

```
 <com.yourpackagename.AutoScrollableTextView
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="This is very very long text to be scrolled"
 />
```

That's it.

Answer (score 9):

Add the following in the textview in XML.

```
android:scrollbars="vertical"
```

And finally, add

```
textView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

in the Java file.

Comment: This does not do kinetic scrolling. Do not use it.

Answer (score 7):

```
yourtextView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

you can scroll it now.

Comment: This is what [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3256305/1364007) already says. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/25026535).

Answer (score 6):

I didn't find TextView scrolling to support the 'fling' gesture, where it continues scrolling after a flick up or down. I ended up implementing that myself because I didn't want to use a ScrollView for various reasons, and there didn't seem to be a MovementMethod that both allowed me to select text and click on links.

Comment: soo... how did you add the fling gesture?

Answer (score 5):

When you are done with scrollable, add this line to the view's last line when you enter anything in the view:

```
((ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.TableScroller)).fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
```

Comment: dude,tablescroller is a view that was identified by the id attribute from the XML that was processed in .. u just try it.. it ll work fine.. its works fr me..

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to use the EditText solution then you might have better luck with:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.yourLayout);
    (TextView)findViewById(R.id.yourTextViewId).setMovementMethod(ArrowKeyMovementMethod.getInstance());
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Add this to your XML layout:

```
android:ellipsize="marquee"
android:focusable="false"
android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
android:scrollHorizontally="true"
android:singleLine="true"
android:text="To Make An textView Scrollable Inside The TextView Using Marquee"
```

And in code you have to write the following lines:

```
textview.setSelected(true);
textView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

Comment: This does not do kinetic scrolling. Do not use it.

Comment: i dont want to ellipsize the end text. how do i do it.

Comment: @SagarNayak use android:ellipsize="none"

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an older post, but this is how I am handling the issue on the Java side.

```
    // Allow textView to scroll
    tv.setSingleLine(true);
    tv.setHorizontallyScrolling(true);
    tv.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
    tv.setMarqueeRepeatLimit(-1); // Infinite
    // TextView must be 'selected'
    tv.setSelected(true);
    // Padding not necessary, but this helps so the text isn't right
    // up against the side of a screen/layout
    tv.setPadding(10, 0, 10, 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

The code below creates an automatic horizontal scrolling textview:

While adding TextView to xml use

```
<TextView android:maxLines="1" 
          android:ellipsize="marquee"
          android:scrollHorizontally="true"/>
```

Set the following properties of TextView in onCreate()

```
tv.setSelected(true);
tv.setHorizontallyScrolling(true);
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem when I was using `TextView` inside the `ScrollView`. This solution has worked for me.

```
scrollView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                description.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);

                return false;
            }
        });

        description.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                description.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);

                return false;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use it like this

```
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:maxLines = "AN_INTEGER"
    android:scrollbars = "vertical"
/>
```

Comment: AN_INTEGER' is incompatible with attribute maxLines (attr) integer min=0.

Comment: what is AN_INTEGER?

Answer (score 1):

Put `maxLines` and `scrollbars` inside TextView in xml.

```
<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:maxLines="5" // any number of max line here.
    />
```

Then in java code.

`textView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());`

Answer (score 1):

whenever you need to **use the ScrollView as parent**, And you also use the scroll movement method with TextView.

And When you **portrait to landscape your device that time occur some issue**. (like) entire page is scrollable but scroll movement method can't work.

if you still need to use ScrollView as parent or scroll movement method then you also use below  desc.

**If you do not have any problems then you use EditText instead of TextView**

see below :

```
<EditText
     android:id="@+id/description_text_question"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:background="@null"
     android:editable="false"
     android:cursorVisible="false"
     android:maxLines="6"/>
```

**Here, the EditText behaves like TextView**

And your issue will be resolved

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer in the wonderful and happy world of JetPack Compose :

```
LazyColumn {
        item {
            Text(
                text = "My Long Text"
            )
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this for over a week and finally figured out how to make this work!

My issue was that everything would scroll as a 'block'. The text itself was scrolling, but as a chunk rather than line by line. This obviously didn't work for me, because it would cut off lines at the bottom. All of the previous solutions did not work for me, so I crafted my own.

Here is the easiest solution by far:

**Make a class file called: 'PerfectScrollableTextView' inside a package, then copy and paste this code in:**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class PerfectScrollableTextView extends TextView {

    public PerfectScrollableTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
        setHorizontallyScrolling(false);
    }

    public PerfectScrollableTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
        setHorizontallyScrolling(false);
    }

    public PerfectScrollableTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
        setHorizontallyScrolling(false);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFocusChanged(boolean focused, int direction, Rect previouslyFocusedRect) {
        if(focused)
            super.onFocusChanged(focused, direction, previouslyFocusedRect);
    }

    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean focused) {
        if(focused)
            super.onWindowFocusChanged(focused);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isFocused() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Finally change your 'TextView' in XML:**

From: `<TextView`

To: `<com.your_app_goes_here.PerfectScrollableTextView`

Comment: 100% Perfect answer. I faced the same issue as you mention in the description. apply many solutions but not work perfectly. but your solution working perfectly in every case. save my time man :) Thanks

Comment: Doesn't work at all for me. No scrolling at all. 

The only problem the other solutions have is the missing kinetic scrolling. Can't see how your solution fixed that.

Comment: @Lothar I'm not sure, this was 7 years ago so I'm sure a lot has changed, sorry about that!

Answer (score 0):

In my case.Constraint Layout.AS 2.3.

Code implementation:

```
YOUR_TEXTVIEW.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

XML:

```
android:scrollbars="vertical"
android:scrollIndicators="right|end"
```

Answer (score 0):

XML - You can use `android:scrollHorizontally` Attribute

Whether the text is allowed to be wider than the view (and therefore can be scrolled horizontally).

May be a boolean value, such as "true" or "false".

Prigramacaly - `setHorizontallyScrolling(boolean)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
android:scrollbars = "vertical"
```

Answer (score 0):

For a vertically *or* horizontally scrollable TextView some of the other answers help, but I needed to be able to scroll both ways.

What finally worked is a ScrollView with a HorizontalScrollView inside of it, and a TextView inside the HSV. It's very smooth and can easily go side to side or top to bottom in one swipe. It also only allows scrolling in one direction at a time so there's none of the jumping side to side while scrolling up or down.

An EditText with editing and cursor disabled works, but it feels terrible. Each attempt to scroll moves the cursor and it requires many swipes to go top to bottom or side to side in even a ~100-line file.

Using `setHorizontallyScrolling(true)` can work, but there's no similar method to allow vertical scrolling, and it doesn't work inside of a ScrollView as far as I can tell (just learning though, could be wrong).