# How do I show only the last 3 lines of text in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a `Text` object in Jetpack Compose whose content is continuously getting longer, but I only want to render the last 3 lines at any given time. Essentially, I'm hoping to mimic the behavior of `TextView`'s `android:gravity="bottom"`, as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12689291/4718598). How would I go about achieving this?

Comment: The gravity attribute in the view system corresponds to the `align` Modifier in Compose. Try that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Text`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary?hl=en#Text(kotlin.String,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.unit.TextUnit,androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontStyle,androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontWeight,androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontFamily,androidx.compose.ui.unit.TextUnit,androidx.compose.ui.text.style.TextDecoration,androidx.compose.ui.text.style.TextAlign,androidx.compose.ui.unit.TextUnit,androidx.compose.ui.text.style.TextOverflow,kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.Int,kotlin.Function1,androidx.compose.ui.text.TextStyle)) has `onTextLayout` parameter with will give you all needed information about the text layout. You can get the number of lines and the offset for the needed line index.

Using [`SubcomposeLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/layout/package-summary#SubcomposeLayout(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,kotlin.Function2)) you can calculate the needed offset using value got from `onTextLayout` before any drawing and apply it. And you need to apply `Modifier.clipToBounds` to prevent redundant text to be drawn.

```
@Composable
fun LimitedText(
    text: String,
    maxBottomLines: Int,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    color: Color = Color.Unspecified,
    fontSize: TextUnit = TextUnit.Unspecified,
    fontStyle: FontStyle? = null,
    fontWeight: FontWeight? = null,
    fontFamily: FontFamily? = null,
    letterSpacing: TextUnit = TextUnit.Unspecified,
    textDecoration: TextDecoration? = null,
    textAlign: TextAlign? = null,
    lineHeight: TextUnit = TextUnit.Unspecified,
    overflow: TextOverflow = TextOverflow.Clip,
    softWrap: Boolean = true,
    style: TextStyle = LocalTextStyle.current,
) {
    SubcomposeLayout(
        // prevent offset text from being drawn
        modifier.clipToBounds()
    ) { constraints ->
        var extraLinesHeight = 0
        val placeable = subcompose(null) {
            Text(
                text = text,
                color = color,
                fontSize = fontSize,
                fontStyle = fontStyle,
                fontWeight = fontWeight,
                fontFamily = fontFamily,
                letterSpacing = letterSpacing,
                textDecoration = textDecoration,
                textAlign = textAlign,
                lineHeight = lineHeight,
                overflow = overflow,
                softWrap = softWrap,
                onTextLayout = { textLayoutResult ->
                    val extraLines = textLayoutResult.lineCount - maxBottomLines
                    if (extraLines > 0) {
                        extraLinesHeight = textLayoutResult.getLineTop(extraLines).roundToInt()
                    }
                },
                style = style,
            )
        }[0].measure(
            // override maxWidth to get full text size
            constraints.copy(maxHeight = Int.MAX_VALUE)
        )
        layout(
            width = placeable.width,
            height = placeable.height - extraLinesHeight
        ) {
            placeable.place(0, -extraLinesHeight)
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
LimitedText(
    LoremIpsum().values.first(),
    maxBottomLines = 3,
)
```

---

Most of time this would be enough, but in case you will need to get the final result of `onTextLayout`, you can calculate the text offset and add one more placeable with `subcompose` which will contain only the needed part of the text, and place only the second placeable.

```
@Composable
fun LimitedText(
    text: String,
    maxBottomLines: Int,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    color: Color = Color.Unspecified,
    fontSize: TextUnit = TextUnit.Unspecified,
    fontStyle: FontStyle? = null,
    fontWeight: FontWeight? = null,
    fontFamily: FontFamily? = null,
    letterSpacing: TextUnit = TextUnit.Unspecified,
    textDecoration: TextDecoration? = null,
    textAlign: TextAlign? = null,
    lineHeight: TextUnit = TextUnit.Unspecified,
    overflow: TextOverflow = TextOverflow.Clip,
    softWrap: Boolean = true,
    onTextLayout: (TextLayoutResult) -> Unit = {},
    style: TextStyle = LocalTextStyle.current,
) {
    SubcomposeLayout(modifier) { constraints ->
        var slotId = 0
        fun placeText(
            text: String,
            onTextLayout: (TextLayoutResult) -> Unit,
            constraints: Constraints,
        ) = subcompose(slotId++) {
            Text(
                text = text,
                color = color,
                fontSize = fontSize,
                fontStyle = fontStyle,
                fontWeight = fontWeight,
                fontFamily = fontFamily,
                letterSpacing = letterSpacing,
                textDecoration = textDecoration,
                textAlign = textAlign,
                lineHeight = lineHeight,
                overflow = overflow,
                softWrap = softWrap,
                onTextLayout = onTextLayout,
                style = style,
            )
        }[0].measure(constraints)
        var substringStartIndex: Int? = null
        val initialPlaceable = placeText(
            text = text,
            // override maxWidth to get full text size
            constraints = constraints.copy(maxHeight = Int.MAX_VALUE),
            onTextLayout = { textLayoutResult ->
                val extraLines = textLayoutResult.lineCount - maxBottomLines
                if (extraLines > 0) {
                    substringStartIndex = textLayoutResult.run {
                        getOffsetForPosition(
                            Offset(1f, getLineTop(extraLines) + 1f)
                        )
                    }
                } else {
                    onTextLayout(textLayoutResult)
                }
            },
        )
        val finalPlaceable = substringStartIndex?.let {
            placeText(
                text = text.substring(startIndex = it),
                constraints = constraints,
                onTextLayout = onTextLayout,
            )
        } ?: initialPlaceable

        layout(
            width = finalPlaceable.width,
            height = finalPlaceable.height
        ) {
            finalPlaceable.place(0, 0)
        }
    }
}
```