# Main.xml in Android

Tags: android, user-interface, scroll

Hello I have a bunch of text on my file which i display. I used the Hello World demo to insert this text. Now Whenever i try to edit main.xml it doesn't happen. If anybody knows why that would be cool but I want to know how to add simple scrolling to my text. I don't think I need to use main.xml right. Is there a way I can just add it to my project?

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class manifesto extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    //Make a new text view passing Activity object
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    //Set a text into view

    tv.setText("A bunch of text.");
    tv.setTextSize(12);

    //set the view into activity view container
    setContentView(tv);    
    }
}
```

Here is the XML file in case you want to see it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<TextView android:text="@+id/TextView01" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
 android:id="@string/hello"></TextView>                        

 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you're calling `setContentView(tv)`, so you're not actually seeing any `Views` from the XML, only the `TextView` you initialized in `onCreate`().  Also, it looks like you've got your `android:text` and `android:id` attributes mixed up in your XML. It should be

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/TextView01" 
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:text="@string/hello" />
```

And for your question on scrolling, see [Making TextView scrollable on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1748977/making-textview-scrollable-in-android).

Comment: OK I deleted everything in the project and just transferred everything under the main.xml. It doesn't show up now. What am I doing wrong? I Deleted all of this code 
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    //Set a text into view

    tv.setText("A bunch of text.");
    tv.setTextSize(12);

    //set the view into activity view container
    setContentView(tv);    
    }
}    and added my bunch of text into main.xml under <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView01"  AndroidText="a bunch of text." and then all the normal stuff what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Make sure it's `android:text`, not AndroidText.  Otherwise, I don't know what's wrong, you haven't posted enough code for me to tell.

Comment: That's all the code i have it's a very simple project i just want to display a bunch of text and have it scroll. Using the basic Hello World app demo.

Comment: Sorry i restarted the program and I didnt edit the java file just main.xml and it worked!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Did you realize what when wrong with your code and why it did not work in first place.
Here is the step by step analysis.

1)  You have here set the layout to the screen in first setp
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

2)  This step is not necessary.

```
////*****
//Make a new text view passing Activity object
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
//Set a text into view

tv.setText("A bunch of text.");
tv.setTextSize(12);   *****////
```

3)  You actually overwrote your layout with your newly created object which was incorrect.
    //set the view into activity view container
    setContentView(tv);

4) Lastly you messed up the ids,

5) MY suggestion is please read topics on view and layouts and their differences and instead of just putting and running the code try to understand the finer aspects of it.

Thanks and best regards
Prasad

Answer (score 0):

The set on the content view was always reset to tv,

```
 setContentView to (R.layout.main to reflect the changes in main.xml
```