# Click through a RecyclerView list item

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` with a `LinearLayoutManager` and an `Adapter`:

```
@Override public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position == 0? R.layout.header : R.layout.item;
}
```

Here's `header.xml`:

```
<View xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/header"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="@dimen/header_height"
    />
```

What I want to achieve is to have a **hole** in the `RecyclerView` where I can click through to anything behind the `RecyclerView`. I tried a lot of combinations the following attributes to no avail:

```
      android:background="@android:color/transparent"
      android:background="@null"
      android:clickable="false"
      android:focusable="false"
      android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
      android:longClickable="false"
```

**How could I make the first item transparent (allowing touch events to anything behind it) in the list, but let it still occupy the space?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could set the `OnClickListener`/`OnTouchListener` of all of your "holes" to the parent of the view behind the `RecyclerView` and delegate any of the `MotionEvent` and touch events to that parent `ViewGroup`'s touch handling.

Update by TWiStErRob:

```
class HeaderViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public HeaderViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        view.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8121491/is-it-possible-to-add-a-scrollable-textview-to-a-listview
                v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true); // needed for complex gestures
                // simple tap works without the above line as well
                return behindView.dispatchTouchEvent(event); // onTouchEvent won't work
            }
        });
```

There's nothing special needed in the XML, just plain views (none of the attributes in the question).
`v.getParent()` is the `RecyclerView` and that long method stops it from starting a scroll gesture while holding your finger on the "hole".

My "hole" view in the list also has a semi-transparent background, but that doesn't matter because we're hand-delivering the touches.

Comment: Hmm, interesting :) I want complex gestures to work (e.g. swipe), so only the touch listener is worth trying.

Comment: Also, you could allow the `RecyclerView` to identify any holes for any of the touch handling you would like to handle, then delegate to the back if the events are holy ;)