# Android "scroll" Text in TextView

Tags: android, string, scroll, textview

I got the following situation:
I have a String with about 40 - 50 Words and a TextView with max. 3 Lines.
Is it possible to get the TextView to Display the a text snippet starting from a specific Word (not the first one) or Regex from the String?
Example:

```
String: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna

Shown in TextView: ...consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy...
```

Comment: you can use TextView method: `setMaxLines` to make the last has `...`, if the line is bigger than max lines, but you want the first, may be need your custom implements.

Comment: Why not manipulate the string before setting it into the textview?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use a ScrollView actually. Just set the `android:maxLines` and `android:scrollbars = "vertical"` properties of textview in layout xml file. Then use the `TexView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod())` in the Code. Bingo!!!! It scrolls. Taken from [`this`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1748977/making-textview-scrollable-in-android) Answer.

Comment: I don't want to enable scrolling, i just want to scroll to specific text pattern and than stay there.

Comment: Your question don't seems to be much clear what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

you can implement the following change to your code:

```
urBtn.setEllipsize(TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
urBtn.setMarqueeRepeatLimit(-1);
```

This will set the text in the button to scroll always when focussed

Comment: Sorry that is not what I want. I don't want the text to be scrollable, i just want it to scroll at a specific position and then stay there.