# add a scrollView to Textview

Tags: android, scroll

i have the following layout in xml

```
<Relativelayout.....
       <TextView 1........../>

       <ImageView........./>

       <Textview 2......../>
</Relativelayout>
```

I need to add vertical scrollview to Textview 2 how to do this i have added the foll code but not working...

```
<LinearLayout>

   <ScrollView >

      <TextView />

   </ScrollView> 
</LinearLayout>
```

please help

Comment: If you simply want to scroll a textview, why dont you use TexViewObject.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod()) as suggested in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1748977/making-textview-scrollable-in-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your activity Do something like this:

```
TextView textDisplayed =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
textDisplayed.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: just add this in layout android:maxLines and android:scrollbars = "vertical" properties of textview in layout xml file. Then use the TexView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod()) in .java

Comment: thanks it worked for me also i also commented what should be added in .java so that it works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Add a ViewGroup (like LinearLayout) between the ScrollView and your TextView. AFAIK, it's mandatory.

Comment: what is AFAIK? in your statement

Comment: AFAIK is an English acronym for "As Far As I Know"

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="352dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

this works for me

Comment: But it showing NULLpointer exception for me as its not able to find the texview id which is inside LL

Comment: sorry the order should be different, LinearLayout->scrolliew->textview. are you sure calling the textview correctly in your code TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.editText1);

Answer (score 0):

this is absolutely fine to add scroview on textView but keep one thing in mind only height of textview should be more then scroll view height

```
<LinearLayout>

   <ScrollView >

      <TextView /> //textView 2

   </ScrollView> 
</LinearLayout>
```