# Action Bar Sherlock List Navigation Spinner: item width marquee?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-actionbar

I use Action Bar Sherlock library to add an action bar to my layout. I set the navigation mode to **ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST** and use a custom adapter to populate the navigation spinner.

the problem is that when a spinner item text is too long, it does not appear completely.

I want it to be like a marquee, how can this be done ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try implementing your own view that marquees text as the selected item view for use by the `Spinner` as opposed to the `R.layout.sherlock_spinner_item` layout.

You'd probably need a `ScrollingTextView` implementation which [can be found by Googling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1748977/making-textview-scrollable-in-android).

Comment: Thanks Jake, it works when I press on the spinner and the items dialog appears, but I need the text of the spinner itself (when not pressed) to scroll, is there a way to do this ?