# Android textView how show full text?

Tags: android, textview

I have used TextView in my application. For example in strings I write some for example text more than 30000 symbol. Time of  text in application show only some symbols. How can I make tyextview to show full text and scroll all text in app?

Comment: look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1748977/making-textview-scrollable-in-android)

Comment: show your textview xml format

Answer (score 1):

you can wrap your text with the **android:singleLine="true"**, and **android:ellipsize="marquee"**.

This will show the full text in the scrolling mode

or you can use android:ellipsize="none" -> this will show wrap the text at left most.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your `TextView` inside a `ScrollView` like this:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: scrollview is indeed one possible solution. But it is not needed. 2 Lines of xml and one line of code will do the same. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1748977/making-textview-scrollable-in-android