# android - how to make a textview scroll?

Tags: android

Actually im showing some data in a textview but its half of the data is going out of the screen so i need help to make a textview scroll or any other thing that can scroll down the screen.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: check this - http://stackoverflow.com/a/3256305/1433187

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Put your TextView inside ScrollView in XML like:

```
 <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="txt2"/>

    </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 3):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1748977/making-textview-scrollable-in-android)

```
   TextView textview= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.your_textview_id);
   textview.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use it this way:

```
<scrollview

(your code)

/>
```