# how to add scrollbars to a textview in android

Tags: java, android

I have defined the function showMeTable() for getting data from sqlite database in DbHelper.java class. Then i call it from WeekDbShow.java class. After getting the table in the form of string , i am setting it to a textView .Here is the part of my DbHelper.java class .

```
public String showMeTable()
    {
        String mStr="";

        mStr=mStr.concat("<body >");
        mStr=mStr.concat("<tr><td align='center'><b>period</b></td><td align='center'><b>Monday</b></td>" +
                "<td align='center'><b>Tuesday</b></td><td align='center'><b>Wednesday</b></td><td align='center'><b>Thrusday</b></td>" +
                "<td align='center'><b>Friday</b></td></tr>");

        String[] columns=new String[]{KEY_ROWID,KEY_PERIOD,KEY_MON,KEY_TUES,KEY_WED,KEY_THRUS,KEY_FRI};//KEY_MON may be instead of weekDay
        Cursor cursor=OurDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE,columns,null,null,null,null,null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while(!cursor.isAfterLast())
                    {
        mStr=mStr.concat("<tr><td>"+(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_PERIOD)))+"</td>" +
                "<td>"+(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_MON)))+"</td><td>"+
                (cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_TUES)))+"</td><td>"+(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_WED)))+"</td>" +
                "<td>"+(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_THRUS)))+"</td><td>"+(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_FRI)))+"</td></tr>");


          cursor.moveToNext();
        }

           mStr.concat("</table></body>");
           return mStr;
    }
```

And this is the part of my WeekDbShow.java class from where i am calling the showMeTable.

```
 String data=myDbHelper.showMeTable();

    //showMe.setText("<b>data</b>");
    showMe.setText(Html.fromHtml(data));
    myDbHelper.close();
```

here is my xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">    
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvTT"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:maxLines = "200"
    android:scrollbars = "vertical"
    />
```

please give me some good solution ,i have all ready tried scrollView in xml.

Comment: Please provide layout file. refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1748977/making-textview-scrollable-in-android or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10904234/android-how-to-make-a-textview-scroll

Comment: Here are my notes about this:  android:maxLines = "AN_INTEGER"

android:scrollbars = "vertical"

              TextView tv = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id. info));
              tv.setMovementMethod( new ScrollingMovementMethod());

Comment: now i have added my xml file

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1748977/making-textview-scrollable-in-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you r using AS then above fix may not work ....try this......
In properties of your TextView in your layout's xml file set:

```
android:scrollbars = "vertical"
```

Answer (score 3):

In properties of your `TextView` in your layout's xml file set:

```
android:scrollbars = "vertical"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try adding scrollable = true and scrollbar = vertical in your text view properties in the layout xml..

Comment: i don,t understand ,plss be more specific.

Comment: What I meant was add android:scrollable="true" and android:scrollbars="vertical" in your XML..

Comment: there is no scrollable field for TextView.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this in programatically(`.class`) by adding this lines

```
yourtextView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
yourtextView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

Refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1748977/making-textview-scrollable-in-android?lq=1) for more details.