# Automatic scrolling of contents of a text view in scroll in a circular fashion Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-gui

I'm building an application that takes data and appends the data in a `textview`. I want the text to be rotating in a vertical style(just as automatic horizontal scrolling ,but I need it to be in vertical style). Can anyone help me in this?  Eg ihave 5 data i would have arranged it in this fashion and the text view layout can show only 5 lines at a time
the following should be in vertical style

1 data1 

2 data2

3 data3

4 data4

5 data5

**when next data comes data 6 :**

1 data1

2 data2

3 data3

4 data4

5 data5 

6 data6

**i should show it as :**

6 data6

1 data1

2 data2

3 data3

4 data4

5 data5

it should be rotating

5 data5 

6 data6

1 data1 

2 data2

3 data3

4 data4

like this

Comment: Refer this  discussion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1748977/making-textview-scrollable-in-android

Comment: elaborate your problem, what exactly you want.? what do you mean by _rotating in vertical style_.?

Comment: So you mean your data should scroll in circular fashion?

Comment: yes it should scroll in acircular fashion

Comment: i think you are looking for text marquee in vertical style. have a look at http://www.hscripts.com/tutorials/html/marquee1.php

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear what you want to say but
if you want your `TextView` to scroll vertically
try this

in XML for textView

```
android:scrollbars="vertical"
```

in JAVA

```
t.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

t is `TextView`