# ListView not scrollable

Tags: android, android-listview

My `ListView` does not receive onScroll events in case it is short and does not fill the whole screen, which is strange, because I have set `fill_parent` as height.
My layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg_login_screen3"
android:orientation="vertical" >



<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/overview_allcars_checkbox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/all_cars"
    android:textSize="14sp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/list_root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
        android:scrollingCache="true" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: maybe your top linearLayout's height shoud be fill_parent, instead of match_parent..

Comment: I think fill_parent and match_parent are equivalent. They behave the same.

Answer (score 0):

You may find this answer useful:-

[Making TextView scrollable on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1748977/making-textview-scrollable-in-android)

Thats what helped me there:

```
<ScrollView
android:id="@+id/SCROLLER_ID"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
android:fillViewport="true">

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/TEXT_STATUS_ID"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1.0"/>

</ScrollView>
```

Mainly you wrap your TextView in a ScrollView.

Comment: I have no TextView I have a ListView and it is a bad idea to put ListView inside a ScrollView. Moreover it would not help me trigger onScrollListener on ListView.

Comment: You're answer is unrelated to the question