# Android:Textview with vertical scrolling text

Tags: android, android-layout

I am finding a tough time setting the textview with vertical scrolling text. In my dialog I have a textview with large text, since dialog is small window I want the textview text to scroll the vertically so that dialog looks good. Below is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FFFFFF" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/fbcancel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/fbcancel" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/fbedittext"
        android:layout_width="230dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
        android:background="@drawable/roundcorners"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/fbhint"
        android:lines="6"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true" />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/fbedittext" >

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/fbshare"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/fbshare"
            android:layout_below="@+id/fbshare"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
            android:entries="@array/fblist" 

            android:visibility="gone"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/fbpeople"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/fbshare"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/fbshare"
            android:layout_below="@+id/fbshare"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/people"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="true" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/fbshare"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
            android:src="@drawable/newfb" />
    </RelativeLayout>



<ScrollView android:id="@+id/textAreaScroller" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="173px" 
        android:layout_x="0px" 
        android:layout_y="25px" 

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/fbedittext"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/fbedittext"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:lines="7"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:text="@string/fbtext" />
</ScrollView> 
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/fbcancel"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:paddingRight="2dp"
        android:src="@drawable/askabud" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I tried placing the scroll view but the textview is going in wrong position. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: "but the textview is going in wrog position" ? Can you explain a bit?

Comment: can you put the screenshot along with the expected outline.

Comment: Refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1748977/making-textview-scrollable-in-android

Answer (score 79, accepted):

**1. Via XML**

```
<ScrollView android:id="@+id/textAreaScroller" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="173px" 
    android:layout_x="0px" 
    android:layout_y="25px" 
    android:scrollbars="vertical">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/fbedittext"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/fbedittext"
    android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
    android:lines="7"        
    android:text="@string/fbtext" />
</ScrollView>
```

---

**2.Via Code**

```
ScrollView scroller = new ScrollView(this);
TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
scroller.addView(tv);
```

OR

**Putting following properties inside your** `<TextView>`

```
android:scrollbars = "vertical"
```

**In the Code**

```
tv.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

Comment: No need of scrollview. Refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1748977/making-textview-scrollable-in-android

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3256305/1318946

Comment: Your suggestion to add `tv.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());` helped me.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting maximum height in textview, it may work for you, like given below

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="100dip" // change dip accordingly
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/fbedittext"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/fbedittext"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:lines="7"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:text="@string/fbtext" />
```

Comment: where's the maximum height in your code?

Answer (score -1):

Inside your ScrollView give one more RelativeLayout and inside that RelativeLayout put your TextView.

Comment: You don't need a RelativeLayout in the middle if you will have only the textview inside it. Adding unnecessary layers may bring performance issues. Only the TextView inside the ScrollView should sufice.