# How to Scroll the text in a TextView without scrolling its background?

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

I am have a textView that has a background and I want to scroll the text that it contains without scrolling the background

```
<TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_image"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text=" .... "
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put your `TextView` into scroll view like described here: [Android:Textview with vertical scrolling text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14434433/androidtextview-with-vertical-scrolling-text) . Then set your background resource as `ScrollView`'s background and make `TextView` background transparent.