# Scrolling Text inside ScrollView not working

Tags: android, scrollview

I have a `ScrollView` inside which i have some fields and in between i have an `TextView` containing lengthy text.

So i want scrollable `TextView` by which  user can scroll whole form as well as the text inside `TextView` depending of the area he chooses to scroll.

This is how my layout looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".BtcActivity">


    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:text="hi" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_desc"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/rel_layout"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:elevation="1dp"
                android:maxLines="5"
                android:paddingBottom="10dip"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:text="@string/dummy" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

I want Something like this

[image]

I also tried solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32095754/textview-scrollable-in-scrollview) & [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22422771/android-scrollable-textview-inside-scrollview) none of them is working in my case.

Comment: Did you see this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1748977/making-textview-scrollable-on-android

Comment: I update your code, replace with above code

Comment: Your question doesn't describe your requirement well

Comment: Can you go in detail?

Comment: Updated my question have a look

Answer (score 1):

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:text="hi" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />


            <ScrollView
                android:fillViewport="true"
                android:id="@+id/sv"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_desc"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/rel_layout"
                    android:elevation="1dp"
                    android:text="hi\n1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n7\n8"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dip"
                    android:scrollbars="vertical"/>

            </ScrollView>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Java file changes

```
ScrollView scrollView = findViewById(R.id.sv);
scrollView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    use this code :-

   <ScrollView android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="hi" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewDirectoryDetailName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Name"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />



        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    >



            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewDirectoryDescription"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"

                android:text="GraphView is a library for Android to programmatically create
flexible and nice-looking diagrams.
It is easy to understand, to integrate and to customize.
Create Line Graphs, Bar Graphs, Point Graphs
or implement your own custom types."
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />
    </LinearLayout>>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: This is not what i wanted i want scrollview which will have multiple elements and a scrollable textview, Your layout does not helps me

Comment: I have sent again answer of this question. please check updated answer. Thanks You

Comment: cool now this is working let me check then i will accept your answer

Comment: @AkshayKatariya Nested scrollview should be parent layout, Check out I have posted standard answer

Answer (score 0):

try this layout and set scrollView nested scrolling true in java code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:text="hi" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />


            <ScrollView
                android:fillViewport="true"
                android:id="@+id/sv"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_desc"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/rel_layout"
                    android:elevation="1dp"
                    android:text="hi\n1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n7\n8"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dip"
                    android:scrollbars="vertical"/>

            </ScrollView>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

java code add this lines should work fine

```
    scrollView = findViewById(R.id.scrollView1);
    tv_desc = findViewById(R.id.tv_desc);


    tv_desc.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
    scrollView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            tv_desc.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);

            return false;
        }
    });

    tv_desc.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            tv_desc.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);

            return false;
        }
    });
```

not required minimum version 21

Comment: @Akshay  check this answer  it support minimum version also