# How to make a TextView scrollable, without using ScrollView?

Tags: android, scroll, textview, scrollview, pinchzoom

I need to implement a custom View object, which extends the TextView and  supports pinch zooming and scrolling of zoomed the text. Android documentation says that the TextView class can take care of its own scrolling without needing a ScrollView container, but I failed to implement this behavior. My custom TextView will have a fixed frame and usually the text which will be shown in it will be vertically larger than the frame. If we pinch-zoom to the text, the text will be larger horizontally as well. Most of the examples I found were using a TextView inside of a ScrollView, but I specifically want to do this only with my TextView extending class, if it is possible.

Thanks in advance

Comment: try this textview.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

Comment: I already tried it. It shows a vertical scrollbar at the start, but does not scroll the text if I slide on the view.

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1748977/making-textview-scrollable-in-android