# TextView is not clickable inside scrollview in listview?

Tags: android

My inflate layout:-

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="100dip"
    android:layout_height="100dip"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/UserImageView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/no_image"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" >
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/UserTitleTextView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="25dip"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="5dip"
        android:paddingRight="28dip"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/UserRecentActivityIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dip"
        android:gravity="bottom|right" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/redDotActivityIconInflateGroupDetail02"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dip"
        android:gravity="bottom|right"
        android:src="@drawable/red_dot_icon" />
</FrameLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayoutMain"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/activityTitleTextViewGroupDetail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingRight="5dip"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/thumbUrlImageView"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" >
        </ImageView>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ArrowImageView"
        android:layout_width="15dip"
        android:layout_height="20dip"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/arrow1" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/ScrollMain"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/activityTitleTextViewGroupDetail"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dip" >

        <com.example.app.EllipsizingTextView
            android:id="@+id/messageTextViewGroupDetail"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:paddingRight="10dip"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="14.5sp" />
    </ScrollView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/StartDateTextViewGroupDetail02"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ScrollMain"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dateTextViewGroupDetail"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/StartDateTextViewGroupDetail02"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="12sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

please find attaced snapshot[image]

Comment: Not sure whether it will help but try to remove android:clickable="true" from your ScrollView and add it to your EllipsizingTextView

Comment: Try to remove "android:clickable="true" in your ScrollView

Comment: Please try my edits...

Comment: Can you show your java code please...

Answer (score 0):

You should have set TextView inside the scrollView property as `android:clickable="true"`. Remove the `cilckable="true"` from scrollview

Edit:

set the below properties in TextView:

`android:maxLines = "AN_INTEGER"`

`android:scrollbars = "vertical"`

Then use:

`textView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod())`

in your code.

Comment: After make TextView Clickable scrollview is not working.Thnx for rly

Comment: Shree the following code still not work textView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod())

Comment: I provided you the code from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1748977/making-textview-scrollable-in-android. Please go through this SO post for more alternate solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Add
 android:clickable="false"
 android:focusable="false"

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `android:duplicateParentState=true` to your text view.

Also set clickable true to your `textview`.

Comment: This code is inflated in listview. Why you don't use the listview listener.

Comment: Because i have a problem it is not click able after scrollview put

Comment: Try to add android:duplicateParentState=true to your scrollview, RelativeLayout and FrameLayout. With this change all these views should take the state from their parent, the listview cell.

Answer (score 0):

Why scrollview??? Uses `android:inputType="textMultiLine"` in your textview.

Comment: using this tag in xml my textview is not scrollable that is the resone m using scrollview

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following attribute to your ScrollView...

```
android:fillViewport="true"
```

...and add the following to any children of your ScrollView...

```
android:clickable="true"
```

This should allow your EllipsizingTextView to fill the ScrollView area as needed.

Comment: @YogeshTatwal Also, make sure any children are set to clickable in your XML file.  I'll adjust my answer...

Comment: Still it is not working but http://stackoverflow.com/a/16480785/1915697 it is working i think it is touch intercept prob