# Text in ListView preventing the click event from being fired in Android

Tags: android, listview

I have a ListView with a custom adapter. I can click on the list elements. However, it only works when clicking outside of the text area of the row. When clicking on the text nothing happens.

I have set the Row layout as:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

....
```

And the text style includes:

```
<item name="android:clickable">false</item>
<item name="android:focusable">false</item>
<item name="android:focusableInTouchMode">false</item>
```

Do you have a solution where I will be able to click anywhere in the row?

Comment: Can you post your adapter code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `android:clickable` to `true` in your text style

```
<item name="android:clickable">true</item>
```

Comment: What if it is inside of a HorizontalScrollView?

Comment: try it,and update here if it is making any difference

Comment: It doesn't work. The click event goes though on anyclick as long as the click is outside of the horizontalscrollview. I also tried adding focusable = false and clickable = true to the horizontalscrollview with no effect.

Comment: see if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16299145/textview-is-not-clickable-inside-scrollview-in-listview