# If I have a RelativeLayout nested within a ScrollView how can I create a link in TextView

Tags: android, eclipse, scrollview, android-relativelayout

I am struggling to make my links clickable within an Android application.  I have tried the following:

```
<ScrollView
<RelativeLayout
<TextView
    ...
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:text="@string/stringName"
    android:linksClickable="true"
    android:autoLink="web"
```

with either

```
<string name="stringName"><a href="http://www.example.com">String</a></string>
```

or

```
<string name="stringName">&lt;a href="http://www.example.com">String&lt;/a></string>
```

while also incorporating

```
((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView)).setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView)).setText(Html.fromHtml(getResources().getString(R.string.stringName)));
```

in my .java

EDIT: I can make my string appear as clickable using the former method in my string.xml file, however, when I click on it nothing happens.  I believe it is because I am clicking on either the relativeLayout or even more likely the ScrollView as opposed to the TextView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this work for me:

```
<string name="stringName"><a href="http://www.example.com">String</a></string>


TextView TextView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
TextView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

In Xml file:

```
Remove this two lines from TextView
android:linksClickable="true"
android:autoLink="web"
```

Comment: This worked for me.  The only way I could get it to work.  It seems that having the lines in text view 'android:linksClickable' and 'android:autoLink' will prevent it from working correctly

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
TextView text1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

Spanned spanned = Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.stringName));
text1.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
text1.setText(spanned);
```

And my strings.xml, it changes at the end replacing `>` for `&gt;`

```
<string name="stringName">&lt;a href="http://www.example.com"&gt;>String&lt;/a&gt;</string>
```

Comment: When I do this, stringName is being displayed as "<a href=.../a>." and is still not clickable.  Is it because I have a textview within a relativeview within a scrollview?

Comment: Searching on internet it seems that elements inside a scrollview are not clickable. But look here, maybe it could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16299145/textview-is-not-clickable-inside-scrollview-in-listview

Answer (score 0):

I am not too sure about nesting a TextView in a scrollView making it not clickable, but you can always make your TextView clickable in your code.
You set an OnClickListener on your TextView, and inside start a new Intent like this :

First inflate the ScrollView and get your textView in the code like this :

```
ScrollView layout = (ScrollView) ScrollView.inflate(this, R.layout.campaign_info_layout, null);
TextView textView = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.textView);
```

Then set the OnClickListener like this ;

```
textView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener (){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.example.com"));
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
```

Comment: whenever I do this my textView is redlined and says it can't be resolved to a type...What am I missing here?

Comment: You probably didn't inflate the ScrollView and the TextView in the code. I edited my answer to add the way to inflate it.