# Using Scrollable Textview in Fragments doesn't reappear when screen is touched

Tags: android, android-fragments, scrollbar, scrollview, textview

I have a image and a textview in a fragment(split screen). I have the image in the top half of the screen and the textview in the bottom half of the screen. I need the textview to be scrollable. I have tried putting a scrollable view around my textview, but that showed full screen and no scrollbar. After reading about scrollable textviews, I discovered there is an attribute for it, so I used "android:scrollbars="vertical". However, when I touch the screen the scrollbar doesn't appear even though there is more text to display. I have implemented an onTouchListener to make sure that screen being touch is active, but that doesn't cause the scrollbar to appear. I have also read this post several times: [Making TextView scrollable on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1748977/making-textview-scrollable-in-android) but I don't see what I'm missing. What causes the scrollbar to display? It does display initially when the screen first appears and then fades away. What am I missing to make the scrollbar reappear when I touch the textview in my fragment?

Here is my xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="@android:color/white"
  android:orientation="vertical"
 >    
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/bio_imageView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"        
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:src="@drawable/bio_pic"/>   
 <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/bio_TextView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"        
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textColor="#000000"   
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:text="@string/bio_html"/>           

 </LinearLayout>
```

Here is the code:

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (VERBOSE) Log.v(TAG, "+++ onCreateView +++");
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bio, parent, false);

    // Displays the title on the Action Bar
    getActivity().setTitle(R.string.bio_title); 


    final TextView mTextView = (TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.bio_TextView);

    v.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {

            //mTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.bio_html)));
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Screen touched", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            return true;
        }

    });

    mTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.bio_html)));
    setRetainInstance(true);        
return v;
}
```

Comment: I found a solution for my own question. Not sure if this is the best solution, but it works well. I used 3 linearlayouts: one main, one for my image and one from my textview. I surrounded the linearlayout surrounding the textview with a scrollview.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for my own question. Not sure if this is the best solution, but it works well. I used 3 linearlayouts: one main, one for my image and one from my textview. I surrounded the linearlayout surrounding the textview with a scrollview. Hope this helps someone. It seems simple, but getting the right combination of layout_heights, weights and widths was tricky for a newbie like myself.

Here is the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:background="@android:color/white"
   android:orientation="vertical"
 >   
<LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:layout_weight="1" >
 <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/bio_imageView"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"    
      android:background="@android:color/black"    
      android:src="@drawable/bio_pic"/>   
</LinearLayout>        
<ScrollView
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layout_weight="1">
<LinearLayout    
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
>
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/bio_TextView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textColor="#000000"   
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:text="@string/bio_html"/>           
</LinearLayout> 
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```