# scroll view programmatically

Tags: java, android, xml

I would need to create a scrollview directly from Java code so I wrote this code (which I use in an AlertDialog).

```
TextView myTextView = new TextView(context);
myTextView.setText("Very long text" + longTextVariable);
ScrollView scroll = new ScrollView(context);
scroll.setBackgroundColor(android.R.color.transparent);
scroll.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
builder.setView(myTextView);
builder.setView(scroll);
```

But it doesn't work because I do not see anything. To make you understand what I'm doing I tell you simply that I need to display text that very long without scroll view are "cut".

Comment: Check out this link: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1748977/making-textview-scrollable-in-android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1748977/making-textview-scrollable-in-android)

Comment: Yes, it works but i want a really ScrollView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At First need ti added TextView in scrollerView then Added this ScrollerView Alert

```
scroll.addView(myTextView);
builder.setView(scroll);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
ScrollView scrlView = new ScrollView(this);
scrlView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

TextView txt = new TextView(this);
txt.setText("test");
scrlView.addView(txt);

setContentView(scrlView);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the `myTextView` first as view in the `builder` and then replace it with `scroll`. That way you only have a empty scrollview.

You need to add the `myTextView` to the `scrollview`, then add the `scrollview` to the `builder`.