# android scrollable textview not working in scrollview

Tags: android, scroll, textview, scrollview

I am developing 1 application in that i need 1 `scrollview` inside this scrollview i need to put scrolling `textview`/webview(that must display some static string) but must scrollable inside scrollview but not working

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/white" >  
    <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/img_view_flag"
            android:layout_marginTop="17dp" 
            android:paddingBottom="20dip">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >



                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_desc"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/rel_layout"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                        android:maxLines="2"
                        android:scrollbars="vertical"
                        android:text="Medium Text"
                        android:paddingBottom="10dip"
                         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:textColor="@color/black" />
     </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

In myjava file i have done...

```
scrollView1 = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView1);
    // scrollView2 = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView2);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_desc);
    tv.setText("this is 1\n"+"this is 2"+"\n this ix 3\n"+"this is 4\n\n"+"this is 5\n" );

    scrollView1.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub Log.v("PARENT",
            // "PARENT TOUCH");
            Log.v("PARENT", "PARENT TOUCH");
            findViewById(R.id.tv_desc).getParent()
                    .requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
            return false;
        }
    });
    tv.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
            Log.v("TextView", "CHILD TOUCH");
            arg0.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

But not working for me.... what wrong or what i am missing?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3256305/1339473 you can scroll by ScrollingMovementMethod

Answer (score 5):

You have to use below line in your code to make textview scrollable..

```
yourTextView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod())
```

Answer (score -1):

Found a solution.

Add following lines towards end of your OnCreate() function

```
    scrollView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            textView.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);

            return false;
        }
    });

    textView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            textView.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);

            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: This is exactly what the OP has done and just as he says, it doesn't work. You need to add Riser's line from the ^ post.