# Android TextView Scrollable

Tags: android, listview, android-intent, textview

I have a textView which size is 16 characters, if it exceeds 16 characters I want to make it scrollable to the user to view remaining characters.
Could any one help me?

I have tried this link [Making TextView scrollable on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1748977/making-textview-scrollable-in-android)

But there is no result?

My TextView Layout:

```
<TextView  
    android:id="@+id/tv1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:maxLength="16"
       android:scrollbars = "vertical"
       android:ellipsize="end"
    android:text="fdgdddhhhdhd"
    />
```

Comment: show your TextView layout

Comment: I added textview please check

Comment: You can use this : TextView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod()); with TextView.setselected(true); ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making TextView Scrollable in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1748977/making-textview-scrollable-in-android)

Answer (score 26):

In your XML layout file:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/message_scroll"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:text="@string/lorem" />
```

In your Java class file:

```
TextView tv = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.message_scroll);
tv.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

Comment: This is amazing but how can I scroll both vertically and horizontally?

Answer (score 5):

Wrap your textview in a scrollview:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
        <TextView  
            android:id="@+id/tv1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
            android:maxLength="16"
            android:scrollbars = "vertical"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:text="fdgdddhhhdhd" />
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your android:maxlength="16" limits the number of characters that can be placed in the TextView to 16

[According to the developer site](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3amaxLength)