# How to make an Android text view scroll

Tags: android, scroll, textview

I am trying to make a textview scroll.

I used :

```
android:ellipsize="marquee"
```

but it's not working

Comment: Try to add `android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"` ,`android:singleLine="true"` and `android:scrollHorizontally="true"`

Comment: @Malko try selecting your textView in this way: textView.setSelected(true);

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/23873454/334402

Comment: It works with textView.setSelected(true). Thanks Jorge

Comment: I'll add like an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

try selecting your textView in this way

```
textView.setSelected(true);
```

This works because when you scroll over an item in a list view, only then does the now-selected text start scrolling. And since this particular TextView isn't focusable or clickable, it will never lose its selection state.

Thanks to **Christopher Orr** for explaining in a easy way in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3700651/2091181)