# TextView grows as user types

Tags: android

I have a horizontal `LinearLayout` with several `TextViews`. As user types some digits into result view, it expands and other `TextViews` are getting smaller. I want all `TextViews` to have fixed width and hide the first digits when the content is too big. I experimented with surrounding result view with `ScrollView` or `setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod()`) or `TableLayout` without luck. [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1748977/making-textview-scrollable-in-android)

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/assignment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="5"
    style="@style/Formula">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/operandFirst"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="50"
        style="@style/FormulaValue" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/operator"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:text="+"
        style="@style/FormulaOperator" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/operandSecond"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="51"
        style="@style/FormulaValue" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:text="="
        style="@style/FormulaEqualSign" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/result"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="101"
        style="@style/FormulaValue" />

    <Space
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image: Updated image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done by defining `weight` to all `textView`, what you already are doing but also set **`android:layout_width="0dp"`** when you are giving `weight`.

**Edit:**

If you don't want grow your `textView` vertically than add `android:singleLine="true"` attribute to every `textView` of your layout.

To remove the unnecessary white space at the right end, remove `android:layout_weight="1"` attribute from `<space... />`

So it would be,

```
<Space
    android:layout_width="20dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp" />
```

Comment: One problem is fixed with your answer - other TextViews have fixed size, great! On the other hand there is unused space after the Space widget (even if I remove its weight attribute). Second issue is that the TextView grows vertically (another lines). I prefer it to hide some digits.

Comment: It is used, there are multiple lines and I need a space at the end of line. I may try to experiment with right margin instead.

Comment: When we removed the Space, weightSum="5" became incorrect. When I removed it, it works like a charm.

Comment: @SanjeetAjnabee Lets remove unneccessary comments to clean up your answer.

Comment: @LeosLiterak weightsum is not essential, if you write it though then also make sure that sum of weight of all child components equal the weightsum.