# How to create scrollable Textview in android

Tags: android, android-widget

I had a requirement where I need to create a scrollable textview in android.

for Example I had a a long Text that needs to displayed in TextView. 
 Initially it should show part of Text with a Hyperlink "showmore" . Click on "showmore" link should display full Text that scrolls the entire layout.

Can anyone help me to create this type of label ("TextView") in Android

Thanks in Advance

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1748977/making-textview-scrollable-in-android

Comment: every TextView is "scrollable" just use any of `View#scroll*` method

Answer (score 1):

n your XML layout file:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:text="@string/hello" />
```

In your Java class file:

```
TextView mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view);
mTextView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want, you can add a ScrollView wrapping your TextView:

```
<ScrollView
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:scrollbars="vertical"
  android:padding="10dp"
  android:layout_margin="5dp">
    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textView"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:textSize="18sp"/>
  </ScrollView>
```