# ScrollView pushes the beneath View and there is no scroll bar

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview

I have an `ImageView`, a `TextView` and another 'ImageView', grouped in a vertical `LinearLayout`.
The TextView should contain long text, so I wrapped it in a `ScrollView`. The first ImageView should be 100dp height, and the third 100dp height. The middle TextView should fill the entire available space, and if the text is too long the a scroll bar should appear.
The entire layout is part of a parent layout, so this layout has only part of the screen available. **To demonstrate it i set the LinearLayout height to be 265dp.**
**The problem** is that the the whole text appears, the scroll bar doesn't appear, and the third bottom ImageView height is squashed.
I'm following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8532016/1869297) post, and this is a screenshot.

[image]

My code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="265dp"
android:background="#BDBDBD"
android:orientation="vertical">


<ImageView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="#FFFF00" />


<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/SCROLLER_ID"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TEXT_STATUS_ID"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:text="bla\nbla\nbla\nbla\nbla\nbla\nbla"/>

</ScrollView>


<ImageView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="#FF00FF" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: is your linearlayout height fixed?

Comment: Increase the lines of text inside your `TextView` and see.

Answer (score 0):

Try this layout :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#BDBDBD"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="#FFFF00" />

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/SCROLLER_ID"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TEXT_STATUS_ID"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="bla\nbla\nbla\nbla\nbla\nbla\nbla"/>

</ScrollView>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="#FF00FF" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="265dp"
    android:background="#BDBDBD" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgtop"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#FFFF00" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgbottom"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#FF00FF" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/SCROLLER_ID"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/imgbottom"
        android:layout_below="@id/imgtop"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TEXT_STATUS_ID"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="bla\nbla\nbla\nbla\nbla\nbla\nbla"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ScrollView
android:id="@+id/SCROLLER_ID"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
android:fillViewport="true">

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/TEXT_STATUS_ID"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1.0"
    android:text="bla\nbla\nbla\nbla\nbla\nbla\nbla"/>

</ScrollView>
```

1. the weight that you assigned to the `TextView` does not have any meaning: It's inside a `ScrollView` (which extends `FrameLayout`, not `LinearLayout`) and even if it did have a meaning it's not what you are looking for - It's just say that it should take most of the space inside the `ScrollView`
2. You gave the `ScrollView` `height` of `wrap_content` - in your case it means that it will take the full height of the `TextView` - thus if the `TextView` height is bigger than the height of the screen - It will take all the height of the screen - thus your last `TextView` will not have enough space.

You can solve it using 3 (or more) methods

1. Assign fixed height to the `ScrollView`
2. Assign weight to the `ScrollView` (and maybe also to the rest of the `Views`)
3. Use the New [PercentRelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html). just assign height percent for the `ScrollView` to capture.