# How to create a terminal/console

Tags: java, android, xml

i wanted to create a terminal/console, where the user can enter commands. I know java, but i'm new to xml, so i wanted to know how i can spawn text under text and if it gets to long it should be scrollable, here's a picture:

[image]

and here's my xml cpde for it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#d1d1d1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="175dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/consoleText"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:hint="Command"
            android:layout_weight="0.99" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Send"
            android:id="@+id/sendButton"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

and here's my code for getting the text:

```
public class FragmentConsole extends Fragment{
    EditText text;
    Button button;
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.console,
                container, false);
        button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.sendButton);
        text = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.consoleText);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Log.v("EditText", text.getText().toString());
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
}
```

So i will use some photoshopped pictures to show what i want to do, so each time i enter a command in this case i will use the example "command one","command two" & "command three", so and if i click the send button after each of them they should apper like this:

[image]

so and if the text reaches this black bar:

[image]

the above added text should get pushed in a scrollview and every new text will also get part of the scrollview, so that you can scroll through your commands later on.
I know this is a long post and i hope it is clear what i want to do and someone will know how i could do this. So thanks in advance :)

Comment: Tip: Why do you use **2** nested LinearLayouts instead of **1** single RelativeLayout?

Comment: I don't i'm new to xml and android app making and for me it worked well so i thought i could do it like so :S

Comment: Well, nested layouts are, in general, something to avoid, if you care for performances. Always keep in mind: the flatter, the better.

Comment: okay, will do in the future ;) you seem to have someknowledge on this do you maybe know how i could do this?

Comment: Google keywords: `android execute command line`

Comment: i googled before and i didn't found anything relating to this topic...

Comment: But I found MANY relevant results, by using those keywords.

Comment: yeah then show me how to because i didn't found anything on how to check if the text i spawn underneath is passing a point and then putting it in a scrollview -.-

Comment: Simply include your TextView in a ScrollView. Done.

Comment: ohh wow, yeah that's obvious but how would i check in java code if my text passed a specific y coordinate and then playce all the text i spawned and further text into a scrollview

Comment: how should i do it then!?

Comment: I can't unerstand your difficulties... **1** - Write the text into the EditText. **2** - Click the Button. **3** - Append the text into the TextView. **4** - Execute the command. Finished.

Comment: this is easy but how can i check if the textview size passed a y-coordinate in this case where my edittextbox is and the put it in a scrollview

Comment: You are misunderstanding the usage of the ScrollView. You don't have to worry about that. The TextView will grow indefinetely inside the ScrollView. Without you having to calculate anything

Comment: You need to dig in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1748977/making-textview-scrollable-in-android?lq=1) direction.

Answer (score 2):

For this task you should consider using `ListView` and add every command as new row in this view. It'll also take care for scrolling and you'r text wont colide with your EditText.

Comment: This is another possibility. Even better, because by doing so the commands can be re-executed without having to type them again.