# Auto-shrink TextView according to screensize

Tags: android

I'm trying to get TextView to wrap according to the device screensize so that the 3 button at the bottom will always be visible at the bottom of screen.

[The layout I'm trying to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0o4jG.png)

I've tried the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8532016/6042723) but the ScrollView doesn't seem to work. The 3 buttons is not visible.

[The bad layout I'm getting :(](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCw3P.png)

Here are my code. Thanks for reading.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:fillViewport="true">
        <TextView
            android:text="@string/default_tnc"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"     
            android:layout_weight="1.0"/>
    </ScrollView>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="bottom">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button 1"/>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button 2"/>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button 3"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You can simply do it by using a`RelativeLayout` as your parent layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is what you need , just copy and paste

```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_above="@+id/ll_layout"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_weight=".8">
    <TextView
        android:text="@string/temp_txt"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        />
   </ScrollView>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/ll_layout"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button 1"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button 2"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:text="Button 3"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add android:layout_weight="1" to your `ScrollView` and change height of ScrollView to 0
Remove android:layout_weight="1" from your `TextView`

```
<ScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:fillViewport="true">
            <TextView
                android:text="@string/default_tnc"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" // or wrap_content     
                />
  </ScrollView>
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

You can RelativeLayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".lActivity">

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/web_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView 
// enter code here
/>
</CrollView>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="#FFFFFF">

  <Button>
  <Button>
  <Button>

</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a `LinearLayout` as the main parent, Just use a `RelativeLayout`. Then just use the `layout_above` attribute in the ScrollView to have it set to be above the .

```
ativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/id_rl_below"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:text="asdhgfahgdsashgaweatlweiutnwaueytluwae ytbluwae ytbluewzybltuewzsyb tzsydgzlu ybeutzybwlutvybwelutyvzewuiybtuwzey btuzwey tluiwg usdbugdslyuggjzsg zsdg sd mgzsdnzsntzsetxseyuxtrutfru xtfrunftu nxut uctr mxr untrxuxdumtrrumxrtmuxrumnrxtumn"
            android:textSize="50dp" />

    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@id/id_rl_below"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button 1" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button 2" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button 3" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

To know more about how to use RelativeLayouts. You can check the Official Android Developers Site -- [RelativeLayout.LayoutParams](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html). Hope this helps. :)