# Is it possible to add a label which scrolls down so you can see the rest of the text?

Tags: android, jquery, smartface.io

Is it possible to add a label which scrolls down so you can see the rest of the text ?

This is what I mean by a scrolling label field:

[image: What I mean by a scrolling label field]

Comment: See ellipsize and scrollHorizontally TextView attributes

Comment: Here is the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1748977/making-textview-scrollable-in-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make the label multiline, and it's text is larger than it's design area, it will automatically have a scroll. You could also add a visible scroll indicator with the `showScrollBar` function. For instance:
`Pages.Page1.Label1.showScrollBar = true;`

Hope that helps! :)