# Android textview that contain lot of text

Tags: android, textview

Hy! I am working on Android app for Cars where I want to show  news of car. So I have 50 lines of text, I want to put all that text in one activity so u can scroll and read that text. Should I use TextView or something else? Should I save that whole text in res/strings.xml ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need scrolling content, the easiest thing to do is place the view to be scrolled in a ScrollView.  This works for any type of view that does not scroll itself, including TextView.

Comment: actually i want to scroll image as well as text as i mentioned in my activity there is one image and below that  detail of image and using scrollview it only scroll text how can i scroll both ?

Comment: Put all the content to scroll in a container such as LinearLayout, then put the LinearLayout inside a ScrollView.  ScrollView will scroll the whole thing for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `TextView` itself. To make it scrollable see this Stackoverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1748977/making-textview-scrollable-in-android). It is recommended to store strings in `strings.xml`

Answer (score 0):

You can use TextView. However, i recommend use the following part in the .xml part:

```
<TextView
    android:text="@string/nameofthetext"
/>
```

nameofthetext should be save in the strings.xml file (You'll find in the values folder)