# Create textview scroll vertical with media player

Tags: android, media

I have a media player to play mp3 file and a text view show content of song mp3.
Now i want text view can scroll vertical when mp3 run. How I can do it?

Answer (score 0):

Just set the

```
android:maxLines = "AN_INTEGER"

android:scrollbars = "vertical"
```

properties of your `TextView` in your layout's xml file.

Then use:

```
yourTextView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

for more detail and reference visit this : [Making TextView scrollable on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1748977/making-textview-scrollable-in-android/3256305#3256305)

Hope this will help you.

Comment: how i can set it auto scroll?