# Fit Scroll View to Available Space in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I have a problem with my ScrollView. I want to fit it inside the space available but i don´t know how.

Now i have my ScrollView and my TextView before one LinearLayout:

```
        <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/previousimage"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/question_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margintop"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/margin_five"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/common_textsize" />

    </ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_options"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_small"
        android:gravity="center|bottom"
        android:orientation="vertical">
```

The problem is that if i have so much text inside my TextView the LinearLayout go down and it hides.I want to scroll the text inside. Without push down the LinearLayout.

I want to take this space for ScrollView automatically to adapt to all screen size.

[See the image Layaout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zo04x.png)

Thank you!

Comment: I think your linear layout is useless here.

Comment: Hi,check this out.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1748977/making-textview-scrollable-in-android

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define LinearLayout before your ScrollView and set ScrollView to above LinearLayout, match_parent. Like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottom_options"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_small"
    android:gravity="center|bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    ...
</LinearLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/previousimage"
    android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_options"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/question_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margintop"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/margin_five"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/common_textsize" />

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Thank you! this work perfect! now i have a problem with "TextView" and text  inside. It show text at the bottom and i want show it in the center of the ScrollView.

Comment: Both ScrollView and TextView has "android:layout_marginTop". I think it is duplicated and so you text goes to the bottom. In addition, if you want to have text "center_horizontal", then you need to change, android:layout_width to "match_parent".

Answer (score 0):

The ScrollView should always `match_parent` (or at least be smaller than the available space) otherwise it just take the same space as its children and so from its perspective, no children is out, so no need to scroll.

Comment: If i setup in ScrollView this: android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" then the LinearLayout hides completely.

Comment: Your linear layout is empty so its height will be 0. If you need to display LinearLayout under the ScrollView, you should embed them into a parent a layout.

Comment: LinearLayout is filled but i have not pasted the content. Now i have this. 

 http://i.stack.imgur.com/zo04x.png

But if i have so much text. ScrollView does´t work and push my LinearLayout outside of screen.