# Autoscroll textview in android studio?

Tags: java, android-studio, textview

I made many searches  for finding  a way to scroll textview vertically . But could not find any way.
My app is for reading  puposes so i need automatic scroll textview  vertically

Please can you help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making TextView scrollable in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1748977/making-textview-scrollable-in-android)

Comment: If your app is for "reading purposes", what do you mean by "automatic"/"autoscroll"? Do you mean that the textview is scrolled by the user, or without the user touching anything?

Comment: Without touching anything. Text should move vertically