# Android TextView not scrolling [C#]

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

Why my TextView field doesn't scroll with finger? Have I missed something?

```
    <TextView
    android:text="Hi! Type help for more info"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="186.0dp"
    android:id="@+id/chat_box"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:maxLines="12"
    android:textSize="12sp" 

    android:overScrollMode="always"
    android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />
```

I've tried solution from another post, but for some reason my TextView doesn't have setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod()) method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making TextView scrollable in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1748977/making-textview-scrollable-in-android)

Comment: it's not duplicate, other post's solution is completely different and doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a scrollview for your textview

```
 private HorizontalScrollView m;
private TextView textview;
```

now on your on create method initialize text view and scrollview

```
 m = (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.antc);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.chat_box);
```

now you can use scroll view

```
 m.smoothScrollTo(0, textView.getBottom());
```

or simply add `TextView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());`
in your code
this should work

Comment: both methods smoothScrollTo() and setMovementMethod() are not available, any reason why?

Answer (score 0):

It is an old thread but as a reference,

I tried all properties of TextView about 'scrolling' in Xamarin.Android but none of them worked.( Maybe I missed something...)
Anyway,
 I could achieve this in another way

```
TextView dynamicTextView = new TextView(this);
dynamicTextView.Text = "long text blablabla ";
dynamicTextView.LayoutParameters = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MatchParent, 500); //Limit the height so you can scroll

ScrollView dynamicScrollView = new ScrollView(this);
 dynamicScrollView.AddView(dynamicTextView);
```