# Can't scroll a textView with a maxLines attribute on Android

Tags: java, android

I'd like to make a TextView scrollable when the maxLines is >= to 10.
I tried this code:

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/powers_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/powers"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:maxLines="10"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:text="Powers"
                android:textSize="@dimen/primary_text_size"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

with this:

```
TextView textPowers = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.powers);
textPowers.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

I can see the scroll bar but the TextView doesn't scroll correctly.
I also tried to use a ScrollView without success.
The only way I found to run it is to set the ScrollView height like this:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
                android:id="@+id/scroll_powers"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="180dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/powers"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                        android:scrollbars="vertical"
                        android:text="Powers"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/primary_text_size"/>


</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

but in this case I would continue to have an height of 180dp even when the lines are less than 10.
What can I do? I've read many problems like this on stackoverflow like: [Making TextView scrollable on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1748977/making-textview-scrollable-on-android) but without success.

Comment: Why did you use nested ScrollView? Is there a ScrollView or listview around that?

Comment: You could attempt to dynamically add the ScrollView in the Java code. You're not limited to mostly xml properties

Comment: @cricket_007 yes, I have a parent ScrollView which contains some LinearLayouts inside.
I want to scroll a TextView inside one of these LinearLayouts