# How to achieve this layout in android in a TextView and ScrollView

Tags: java, android

Can anyone please tell me how I can achieve this?  It will display a lot of scrollable text so I think that I am off to the right start.  It will be dynamic and be able to be created at runtime.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0">

    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#477046">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtViewLeft"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:text="A1" />

    </ScrollView>

    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#468490"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/scrollView1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtViewRight"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:text="This is some sample text that I have added.  Thank you for helping" />

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Any help you can give is greatly appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: You don't need to create the Views at runtime. Just fill the TextView(s) with text. That's all.

Comment: Thank you for the reply however I am not sure how to get the 'red' text above to line up with the first line of the orange text.  Hopefully someone on here is a android development/layout master

Comment: This is a use case for RelativeLayout. Simply align both the "red" and the "orange" TextView tops to the bottom of an invisible "dummy" View. And the "orange" one would also be aligned to the "red" one's right

Comment: Thank you for replying but I have alot to learn regarding relative layout. I have updated the code above but I am still unsure how to tie scrollView1 and scrollView2 together. Can you please show me how to do this? As the text grows, will the A1 and the actual text scroll together?   Do I have to create the dummy view for every A1, A2, A3 entry?

Comment: Both the TextViews and their dummy must reside in the same ScrollView. so they all scoll together..

Comment: When putting both txtviews under the same ScrollView, I get "ScrollView can host only one direct child"

Comment: This is because the ScrollView should contain the RelativeLayout as well.

Comment: Possibly, the dummy View becomes useless, then - just align both the TextViews to the parent top... Are you sure you actually need ScrollViews?

Comment: well the text can get quite large so I was under the impression that I needed to use a scroll view.  Is there any way you can correct the xml I have above to work?  I am having the darndest time with this thing

Comment: You don't need it, then. See: https://www.stackoverflow.com/a/3256305/2649012. But in this case you'll just need one RelativeLayout as a global container and a View for each TextView pair. Otherwise, you might want to use a ListView or a RecyclerView to contain the TextViews as custom rows. But it seems an overkill, to me.