# Add scrollbar to text can't be done

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollbar

Been trying for almost a week to achieve a trivial scrollbar in a textview. I asked here several times and nobody produces working code. When I try this I get an NPE.

Want a scrollbar? Then we're going to force you to program XML, we're going to force you to wrap it in layout and we force you to use a scrollview and it still won't work. What happened to keeping it simple?

> Place the TextView inside a ScrollView
>
> https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html
>
> xml
>
> ```
> <LinearLayout
>     android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent"
>     android:orientation="vertical" >
> </LinearLayout>
> ```
>
> And then in the activity:
>
> LinearLayout lin = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
>
> TextView textView = new TextView(this); textView.setText("You are in a
>   dungeon."); textView.setMaxLines(4);
>
> lin.addView(textView);

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: dev.game.adventure, PID: 12085
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{dev.game.adventure/dev.game.adventure.FullscreenActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.LinearLayout.addView(android.view.View)' on a null object reference
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.LinearLayout.addView(android.view.View)' on a null object reference
                      at dev.game.adventure.FullscreenActivity.onCreate(FullscreenActivity.java:157)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767) 
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8785', transport: 'socket'

Then I try the following to get a bloody `IllegalStateException` when all I'm trying to do is achieve a simple scrollbar to a text.

```
  this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen);

        LinearLayout lin = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);

        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setText("You are in a dungeon.");
        textView.setMaxLines(4);

        lin.addView(textView);
```

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{dev.game.adventure/dev.game.adventure.FullscreenActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
                   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:4915)

Then I try this code and naturally it is not working. My Android game starts with out the simple scrollbar and my textview overflows the game image. Why would anybody want this behavior as default? Why would anybody need overflow as default behavior? I want my money back for Android when it can't even render a simple scrollbar.

[image]

Then I try this.

```
LinearLayout lin = new LinearLayout(this);

tbl.addView(tr);
TableRow tr2=new TableRow(this);


TextView textView = new TextView(this);
textView.setText("You are in a dungeon.");
textView.setMaxLines(4);

lin.addView(textView);
ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);

tr2.addView(sv);
TableRow.LayoutParams params = (TableRow.LayoutParams) sv.getLayoutParams();
params.span = 6; //amount of columns you will span
sv.setLayoutParams(params);

tbl.addView(tr2);
```

And now I can prove that it doesn't work either. Now there is no textview at all. And no comment can change this.

[image]

Comment: what exactly you want ? you want scroll to be enabled in a textview or you want the linear layout to be scroll-able?

Comment: @PreethiRao I'm updating a textview and I want it to scroll instead of destroying my entire layout. Destroying the entire layout is the default faulty behavior of this textview. Scrolling should be default behavior.

Comment: are you wrapping your layout inside scrollview ?

Comment: @PreethiRao I tried that too. Nothing works. Just look at how many questions on this site try to solve this problem. I can't use XML.

Answer (score 0):

> Want a scrollbar? Then we're going to force you to program XML, we're going to force you to wrap it in layout and we force you to use a scrollview and it still won't work. What happened to keeping it simple?

What I understand from this is that you simply want to make your `TextView` scrollable with this complicated solution which is not working in your case.

You don't need to do all that to add scroll in your `TextView` just refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3256305/7089172).

My implementation,

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="@string/very_long_text"
        android:maxLines="3"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView myTextView = findViewById(R.id.text_view);
        myTextView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
    }
}
```

[Screen Shot](https://prnt.sc/hd7eei)

Hope this helps.

Comment: but i don't use xml. in fact i can't use xml. it crashes my app.