# Implement Scrollable Textview

Tags: android, textview

By Default I need to show TextView as I mentioned in Below Image with three Dots.

[image]

Once I click on TextView, I need to expand and make as scrollable.(Reference screenshot is added here)

[image]

Any Help to do this in android app?

Comment: What had you tried so far? *Any Help to do this in android wear app?* this is not a valid question on StackOverflow

Comment: I have tried with android:ellipsize="end"
android:maxLines="1"

Comment: You need to implement custom view(or find library which implements it already)

Comment: This is my TextView                                                                     
   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="3"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="This is Sample Text This is Sample Text This is Sample Text This is Sample Text This is Sample Text This is Sample TextThis is Sample Text This is Sample Text"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
        android:textSize="16px" />

Comment: Implement custom view - Can you give me any reference link?

Comment: No, StackOverflow is not human search engine

Comment: I know StackOverflow is not human search engine. I just asked for a suggestion.

Comment: [Asking for suggestion is off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: You can refer to the following link --- [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1748977/making-textview-scrollable-on-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1748977/making-textview-scrollable-on-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="5"
            android:text="@string/str" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**and java code**

```
ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scroll);
         TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);

        scrollView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                textView.setEllipsize(null);
                textView.setMaxLines(100);
                return false;
            }
        });
```

> OUTPUT

**NORMAL**

[image]

**WHEN SCROLL**

[image]

Comment: @kavie happy to help you

Answer (score 0):

By default your TextView should have following property

```
  android:layout_height="30dp" 
  android:ellipsize="end" 
  android:maxLines="3"
```

In onTouchListener of TextView disable ellipsize and maxLine property at runtime as follows

```
 textView.setMaxLines(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
 textView.setEllipsize(null);
 textView.setScrollContainer(true); // make scrollable
```

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class like below

```
class ExpandableTextView extends RelativeLayout implements View.OnClickListener {

private static final String TAG = ExpandableTextView.class.getSimpleName();

/* The default number of lines */
private static final int MAX_COLLAPSED_LINES = 8;

/* The default animation duration */
private static final int DEFAULT_ANIM_DURATION = 300;

/* The default alpha value when the animation starts */
private static final float DEFAULT_ANIM_ALPHA_START = 0.7f;
private final String MORE = "more";
private final String LESS = "";
protected TextView mTv;
protected TextView mButton; // Button to expand/collapse
private boolean mRelayout;
private boolean mCollapsed = true; // Show short version as default.
private int mCollapsedHeight;
private int mTextHeightWithMaxLines;
private int mMaxCollapsedLines;
private int mMarginBetweenTxtAndBottom;
private Drawable mExpandDrawable;
private Drawable mCollapseDrawable;
private int mAnimationDuration;
private float mAnimAlphaStart;
private boolean mAnimating;
/* Listener for callback */
private OnExpandStateChangeListener mListener;

/* For saving collapsed status when used in ListView */
private SparseBooleanArray mCollapsedStatus;
private int mPosition;

public ExpandableTextView(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

public ExpandableTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(attrs);
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public ExpandableTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init(attrs);
}

private static boolean isPostHoneycomb() {
    return Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB;
}

private static boolean isPostLolipop() {
    return Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP;
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
private static void applyAlphaAnimation(View view, float alpha) {
    if (isPostHoneycomb()) {
        view.setAlpha(alpha);
    } else {
        AlphaAnimation alphaAnimation = new AlphaAnimation(alpha, alpha);
        // make it instant
        alphaAnimation.setDuration(0);
        alphaAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
        view.startAnimation(alphaAnimation);
    }
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
private static Drawable getDrawable(@NonNull Context context, @DrawableRes int resId) {
    Resources resources = context.getResources();
    if (isPostLolipop()) {
        return resources.getDrawable(resId, context.getTheme());
    } else {
        return resources.getDrawable(resId);
    }
}

private static int getRealTextViewHeight(@NonNull TextView textView) {
    int textHeight = textView.getLayout().getLineTop(textView.getLineCount());
    int padding = textView.getCompoundPaddingTop() + textView.getCompoundPaddingBottom();
    return textHeight + padding;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (mButton.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE) {
        return;
    }

    mCollapsed = !mCollapsed;
    mButton.setText(mCollapsed ? MORE : LESS);

    if (mCollapsedStatus != null) {
        mCollapsedStatus.put(mPosition, mCollapsed);
    }

    // mark that the animation is in progress
    mAnimating = true;

    Animation animation;
    if (mCollapsed) {
        animation = new ExpandCollapseAnimation(this, getHeight(), mCollapsedHeight);
    } else {
        animation = new ExpandCollapseAnimation(this, getHeight(), getHeight() +
                mTextHeightWithMaxLines - mTv.getHeight());
    }

    animation.setFillAfter(true);
    animation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            applyAlphaAnimation(mTv, mAnimAlphaStart);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            // clear animation here to avoid repeated applyTransformation() calls
            clearAnimation();
            // clear the animation flag
            mAnimating = false;

            if (mCollapsed) {
                mTv.setSingleLine(true);
                mButton.setText(MORE);
                mTv.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.END);
            } else {
                mButton.setText("");
                mTv.setSingleLine(false);

            }

            // notify the listener
            if (mListener != null) {
                mListener.onExpandStateChanged(mTv, !mCollapsed);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        }
    });

    clearAnimation();
    startAnimation(animation);
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    // while an animation is in progress, intercept all the touch events to children to
    // prevent extra clicks during the animation
    return mAnimating;
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    // If no change, measure and return
    if (!mRelayout || getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        return;
    }
    mRelayout = false;

    // Setup with optimistic case
    // i.e. Everything fits. No button needed
    mButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mTv.setMaxLines(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

    // Measure
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

    // If the text fits in collapsed mode, we are done.
    if (mTv.getLineCount() <= mMaxCollapsedLines) {
        return;
    }

    // Saves the text height w/ max lines
    mTextHeightWithMaxLines = getRealTextViewHeight(mTv);

    // Doesn't fit in collapsed mode. Collapse text view as needed. Show
    // button.
    if (mCollapsed) {
        mTv.setMaxLines(mMaxCollapsedLines);
    }
    mButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    // Re-measure with new setup
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

    if (mCollapsed) {
        // Gets the margin between the TextView's bottom and the ViewGroup's bottom
        mTv.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mMarginBetweenTxtAndBottom = getHeight() - mTv.getHeight();
            }
        });
        // Saves the collapsed height of this ViewGroup
        mCollapsedHeight = getMeasuredHeight();
    }
}

public void setOnExpandStateChangeListener(@Nullable OnExpandStateChangeListener listener) {
    mListener = listener;
}

public void setText(@Nullable CharSequence text, @NonNull SparseBooleanArray collapsedStatus, int position) {
    mCollapsedStatus = collapsedStatus;
    mPosition = position;
    boolean isCollapsed = collapsedStatus.get(position, true);
    clearAnimation();
    mCollapsed = isCollapsed;
    //mButton.setText(mCollapsed ? MORE : LESS);
    setText(text);
    getLayoutParams().height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    requestLayout();
}

@Nullable
public CharSequence getText() {
    if (mTv == null) {
        return "";
    }
    return mTv.getText();
}

public void setText(@Nullable CharSequence text) {
    mRelayout = true;
    mTv.setText(text);
    setVisibility(TextUtils.isEmpty(text) ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
}

@Override
protected void onFinishInflate() {
    super.onFinishInflate();
    findViews();
}

private void init(AttributeSet attrs) {
    TypedArray typedArray = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.ExpandableTextView);
    mMaxCollapsedLines = typedArray.getInt(R.styleable.ExpandableTextView_maxCollapsedLines, MAX_COLLAPSED_LINES);
    mAnimationDuration = typedArray.getInt(R.styleable.ExpandableTextView_animDuration, DEFAULT_ANIM_DURATION);
    mAnimAlphaStart = typedArray.getFloat(R.styleable.ExpandableTextView_animAlphaStart, DEFAULT_ANIM_ALPHA_START);
    mExpandDrawable = typedArray.getDrawable(R.styleable.ExpandableTextView_expandDrawable);
    mCollapseDrawable = typedArray.getDrawable(R.styleable.ExpandableTextView_collapseDrawable);

    if (mExpandDrawable == null) {
        mExpandDrawable = getDrawable(getContext(), R.drawable.ic_expand_more_black_24dp);
    }
    if (mCollapseDrawable == null) {
        mCollapseDrawable = getDrawable(getContext(), R.drawable.ic_expand_less_black_24dp);
    }

    typedArray.recycle();

    // default visibility is gone
    setVisibility(GONE);
}

private void findViews() {
    mButton = (TextView) getChildAt(0);
    //mButton.setText(mCollapsed ? MORE : LESS);
    mButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    mTv = (TextView) getChildAt(1);
    mTv.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public interface OnExpandStateChangeListener {
    /**
     * Called when the expand/collapse animation has been finished
     *
     * @param textView   - TextView being expanded/collapsed
     * @param isExpanded - true if the TextView has been expanded
     */
    void onExpandStateChanged(TextView textView, boolean isExpanded);
}

class ExpandCollapseAnimation extends Animation {
    private final View mTargetView;
    private final int mStartHeight;
    private final int mEndHeight;

    public ExpandCollapseAnimation(View view, int startHeight, int endHeight) {
        mTargetView = view;
        mStartHeight = startHeight;
        mEndHeight = endHeight;
        setDuration(mAnimationDuration);
    }

    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
        final int newHeight = (int) ((mEndHeight - mStartHeight) * interpolatedTime + mStartHeight);
        mTv.setMaxHeight(newHeight - mMarginBetweenTxtAndBottom);
        if (Float.compare(mAnimAlphaStart, 1.0f) != 0) {
            applyAlphaAnimation(mTv, mAnimAlphaStart + interpolatedTime * (1.0f - mAnimAlphaStart));
        }
        mTargetView.getLayoutParams().height = newHeight;
        mTargetView.requestLayout();
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(int width, int height, int parentWidth, int parentHeight) {
        super.initialize(width, height, parentWidth, parentHeight);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean willChangeBounds() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

You can use this class with in a scrollview

```
<com.util.ExpandableTextView
                       android:id="@+id/tvDescription"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:ellipsize="end"
                        android:maxLines="3"
                        android:text="@string/dummy_text"
                        app:animation_duration="1000" />
```

and you can toggle using

```
tvDescription.toggle();
```

Answer (score 0):

`textView.setMaxLines(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
 textView.setEllipsize(null);
 textView.setScrollContainer(true);`

use That In Java when You Initialize TextView Object

you can also get in XML Via ScrollView Tag.Where TextView Child of ScrollView And TextView must be multi line