# ScrollView content is incomplete until I rotate screen

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am logging my app into ScrollView using method

```
addLog(View view, String what)
```

New lines should be appended to top of ScrollView so user can see all of them starting from nr1 (like at Picture 3)

Picture 1 - after start - previous lines are gone  - WHAT IS WRONG ? View is not scrollable
[image]

Picture 2 - screen rotate - all OK, view is scrollable
[image]

Picture 3 - screen rotated again to original position - all OK, view is scrollable
[image]

XML

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    tools:context="cz.nielsenadmosphere.androiddemo.NlsCZdemo1.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/screen"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@color/primary"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.SimpleExoPlayerView
            android:id="@+id/player_view"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            app:use_controller="false">

        </com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.SimpleExoPlayerView>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/seekBarLL"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/screen"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@color/primary_dark"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/btns"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/seekBarLL"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@color/primary"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_play"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/txt_play" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_pause"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/txt_pause" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_end"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/txt_end" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/labels"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btns"
        android:background="@color/primary_light"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_label1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="playHead:"
            android:textColor="@color/secondary_text"
            android:padding="5dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_playtime"
            android:layout_width="100sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="0"
            android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
            android:padding="5dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_label2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="status:"
            android:textColor="@color/secondary_text"
            android:padding="5dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_playStatus"
            android:layout_width="100sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="null"
            android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
            android:padding="5dp"/>


    </LinearLayout>


    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/labels"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">

            <!-- height must be wrap_content -->
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/scrollViewText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="3dip"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                >
            </TextView>

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

java.class

```
    public class displayLogScreen extends Activity{

    static int logPosition = 0;
    static String logTotal = "";
    static String logPart = "";

    private static String TAG = "displayLogScreen";

    static ScrollView scrollView;

    public static void addLog(View view, String what) {


        Log.i(TAG, "addLog what=" + what);

        Calendar logCal = Calendar.getInstance();
        DecimalFormat mFormat= new DecimalFormat("00");
        String logTime =  logCal.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "." + mFormat.format(logCal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1) + "." + mFormat.format(logCal.get(Calendar.DATE))+ " " + mFormat.format(logCal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)) + ":" + mFormat.format(logCal.get(Calendar.MINUTE)) + ":" + mFormat.format(logCal.get(Calendar.SECOND));

        // just for test
        what = "fooo";

        logPosition ++;
        logPart = "("+ logPosition + ") " + logTime + " " + what + "\n";
        logTotal = logPart + logTotal;

        // add log to ScrollView
        TextView txt_logs = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.scrollViewText);
        txt_logs.setText(logTotal);



        // if Error - add Toast
        // if (what.substring(0,5).equals("ERROR"))
        //    Toast.makeText(view.getContext() , what, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}
```

Comment: Try adding `android:fillViewport="true"` to `ScrollView `

Comment: fixed by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1748977/making-textview-scrollable-on-android/3256305#3256305

Answer (score 0):

You should specify TextView height MatchParent and android:textAlignment="textStart" As you are using single text view to append the entire log.

Here is something like this

```
                <TextView
                android:id="@+id/scrollViewText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:padding="3dip"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textAlignment="textStart"/>
```

And scrollview's

```
android:fillViewport="true"
```