# ConstraintLayout inside a ScrollView

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I'm building an app with the following Android layout resource, and it appears well in both the Android Studio Preview and on the phone as the image shown.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline_article_header"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="@dimen/guideline_article_header" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/photo"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/article_image"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline_article_header"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/empty_detail" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/photo_background_protection"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline_article_header"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/article_byline"
        style="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline_article_header"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:text="Jan 1, 1912 by JackLondon" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/article_title"
        style="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/detail_title_text_size"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/article_byline"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:text="The Scarlet Plague" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/article_body"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:textColorLink="@color/colorAccent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        tools:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas et efficitur nunc, nec tincidunt eros. Quisque pharetra quam quam. Ut eleifend nulla eros, tempus mattis augue lacinia eget. Praesent dignissim, tellus sit amet pulvinar pretium, augue turpis congue dui, non tempor nisi est a diam. Proin id malesuada nibh. Phasellus fermentum neque lorem, at rutrum enim vehicula vel. Curabitur et enim pretium, euismod nunc in, pretium dolor. Nullam varius eros ut massa condimentum porttitor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Proin nulla diam, dapibus maximus nulla et, maximus congue risus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Duis vel augue ut diam euismod varius. Vestibulum quam magna, convallis blandit vulputate sed, elementum et odio. Maecenas efficitur sem volutpat luctus euismod. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Pellentesque facilisis sapien consequat erat sodales aliquet. Maecenas enim nisi, dignissim non vulputate commodo, tempus ut arcu. Suspendisse potenti. Nulla facilisi. Nam vestibulum orci ex, ac pulvinar elit dapibus ac. Curabitur ut elit justo. Aenean sit amet erat finibus, laoreet lectus quis, eleifend orci. Donec feugiat dui ut nisl euismod auctor. Donec neque magna, tincidunt in tortor ac, fermentum laoreet velit. Sed mollis et ligula non ullamcorper. Etiam at rhoncus tortor. Mauris hendrerit commodo euismod. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Quisque maximus orci a neque tempus pellentesque. Sed erat erat, ultrices eget arcu ac, laoreet cursus odio. Maecenas tristique aliquet vestibulum. Curabitur nec nisi ante. Suspendisse sed dui faucibus, mattis libero maximus, ullamcorper enim. Nulla sodales tellus at tristique fermentum. Fusce sapien nunc, imperdiet vitae arcu et, luctus euismod massa. Proin sed molestie lacus. Nulla vitae ipsum ac orci mattis facilisis. Proin massa risus, cursus et purus vitae, luctus mattis ante. Nulla sagittis id mauris a luctus. Suspendisse blandit orci sit amet purus rhoncus consequat. Duis sapien tortor, interdum mollis tempus sit amet, ullamcorper fringilla mauris. Cras at felis fringilla quam vulputate scelerisque. Sed vestibulum mollis odio elementum lobortis. Proin consequat efficitur neque non varius. Integer in finibus neque, a eleifend ligula. Quisque id faucibus sapien, id porttitor enim. Integer malesuada odio diam, ut sollicitudin nisi egestas ac. Duis sit amet libero purus." />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

However, the article_body `TextView` may be scrollable, so I tried to surround the `ConstraintLayout` by `ScrollView`, but the `ConstraintLayout` takes only a portion from the screen as shown in the image below.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.constraint.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideline_article_header"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="@dimen/guideline_article_header" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/photo"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/article_image"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline_article_header"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/empty_detail" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@drawable/photo_background_protection"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline_article_header"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/article_byline"
            style="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline_article_header"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            tools:text="Jan 1, 1912 by JackLondon" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/article_title"
            style="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/detail_title_text_size"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/article_byline"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            tools:text="The Scarlet Plague" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/article_body"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:textColorLink="@color/colorAccent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
            tools:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas et efficitur nunc, nec tincidunt eros. Quisque pharetra quam quam. Ut eleifend nulla eros, tempus mattis augue lacinia eget. Praesent dignissim, tellus sit amet pulvinar pretium, augue turpis congue dui, non tempor nisi est a diam. Proin id malesuada nibh. Phasellus fermentum neque lorem, at rutrum enim vehicula vel. Curabitur et enim pretium, euismod nunc in, pretium dolor. Nullam varius eros ut massa condimentum porttitor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Proin nulla diam, dapibus maximus nulla et, maximus congue risus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Duis vel augue ut diam euismod varius. Vestibulum quam magna, convallis blandit vulputate sed, elementum et odio. Maecenas efficitur sem volutpat luctus euismod. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Pellentesque facilisis sapien consequat erat sodales aliquet. Maecenas enim nisi, dignissim non vulputate commodo, tempus ut arcu. Suspendisse potenti. Nulla facilisi. Nam vestibulum orci ex, ac pulvinar elit dapibus ac. Curabitur ut elit justo. Aenean sit amet erat finibus, laoreet lectus quis, eleifend orci. Donec feugiat dui ut nisl euismod auctor. Donec neque magna, tincidunt in tortor ac, fermentum laoreet velit. Sed mollis et ligula non ullamcorper. Etiam at rhoncus tortor. Mauris hendrerit commodo euismod. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Quisque maximus orci a neque tempus pellentesque. Sed erat erat, ultrices eget arcu ac, laoreet cursus odio. Maecenas tristique aliquet vestibulum. Curabitur nec nisi ante. Suspendisse sed dui faucibus, mattis libero maximus, ullamcorper enim. Nulla sodales tellus at tristique fermentum. Fusce sapien nunc, imperdiet vitae arcu et, luctus euismod massa. Proin sed molestie lacus. Nulla vitae ipsum ac orci mattis facilisis. Proin massa risus, cursus et purus vitae, luctus mattis ante. Nulla sagittis id mauris a luctus. Suspendisse blandit orci sit amet purus rhoncus consequat. Duis sapien tortor, interdum mollis tempus sit amet, ullamcorper fringilla mauris. Cras at felis fringilla quam vulputate scelerisque. Sed vestibulum mollis odio elementum lobortis. Proin consequat efficitur neque non varius. Integer in finibus neque, a eleifend ligula. Quisque id faucibus sapien, id porttitor enim. Integer malesuada odio diam, ut sollicitudin nisi egestas ac. Duis sit amet libero purus." />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The height of your constraint layout should be `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` then set the height of `@+id/article_body` to `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` as well.

Comment: wrap_content works well when there is enough content(in this case a super long text string) to stretch to the bottom of the screen, but it doesn't work if there is not enough, anyway to make it work when there is not enough content?

Answer (score 1):

Working with code as @tgrable said found a straing behavier of ConstraintLayout.

```
app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="@dimen/guideline_article_header"
```

guide line percentage is not set to phone screen Height but its setting with ConstraintLayout height which means if `@+id/article_body` text decreases it will decrease and as well to increase. As mentioned in question

> However, the article_body TextView may be scrollable,
>   Blockquote

if you only want to scroll `TextView` then [Visit this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1748977/making-textview-scrollable-on-android) or make only the `TextView` Scrollable like below

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/article_body"
        style="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas et efficitur nunc, nec tincidunt eros. Quisque pharetra quam quam. Ut eleifend nulla eros, tempus mattis augue lacinia eget. Praesent dignissim, tellus sit amet pulvinar pretium, augue turpis congue dui, non tempor nisi est a diam. Proin id malesuada nibh. Phasellus fermentum neque lorem, at rutrum enim vehicula vel. Curabitur et enim pretium, euismod nunc in, pretium dolor. Nullam varius eros ut massa condimentum porttitor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Proin nulla diam, dapibus maximus nulla et, maximus congue risus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Duis vel augue ut diam euismod varius. Vestibulum quam magna, convallis blandit vulputate sed, elementum et odio. Maecenas efficitur sem volutpat luctus euismod. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Pellentesque facilisis sapien consequat erat sodales aliquet. Maecenas enim nisi, dignissim non vulputate commodo, tempus ut arcu. Suspendisse potenti. Nulla facilisi. Nam vestibulum orci ex, ac pulvinar elit dapibus ac. Curabitur ut elit justo. Aenean sit amet erat finibus, laoreet lectus quis, eleifend orci. Donec feugiat dui ut nisl euismod auctor. Donec neque magna, tincidunt in tortor ac, fermentum laoreet velit. Sed mollis et ligula non ullamcorper. Etiam at rhoncus tortor. Mauris hendrerit commodo euismod. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Quisque maximus orci a neque tempus pellentesque. Sed erat erat, ultrices eget arcu ac, laoreet cursus odio. Maecenas tristique aliquet vestibulum. Curabitur nec nisi ante. Suspendisse sed dui faucibus, mattis libero maximus, ullamcorper enim. Nulla sodales tellus at tristique fermentum. Fusce sapien nunc, imperdiet vitae arcu et, luctus euismod massa. Proin sed molestie lacus. Nulla vitae ipsum ac orci mattis facilisis. Proin massa risus, cursus et purus vitae, luctus mattis ante. Nulla sagittis id mauris a luctus. Suspendisse blandit orci sit amet purus rhoncus consequat. Duis sapien tortor, interdum mollis tempus sit amet, ullamcorper fringilla mauris. Cras at felis fringilla quam vulputate scelerisque. Sed vestibulum mollis odio elementum lobortis. Proin consequat efficitur neque non varius. Integer in finibus neque, a eleifend ligula. Quisque id faucibus sapien, id porttitor enim. Integer malesuada odio diam, ut sollicitudin nisi egestas ac. Duis sit amet libero purus."
        android:textColorLink="@color/colorAccent" />
```