# Dynamic scrollable TextView inside LinearLayout

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

I'm creating a interface with an image, a textview and two buttons. The interface is not screen-size full, it's only like partial of the screen (like popup message). The position of the image and the button are fixed, but the content of textview is dynamic (pass through function from other file).

I was hoping the textview is flexible but have some height limit; meaning like if only one word is pass through to this interface, the interface would be like normal; but if a long string is pass through, the interface would expand a little bit but have a maximum to hit.

Here is what I currently do:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="16dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="56dp"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:tint="@color/colorAccent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_error" />

        <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                android:paddingRight="16dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                tools:text="title" />

        </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp">

            <TextView android:id="@+id/btn_back"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/grey_darker_rect_selector"
                android:foreground="?selectableItemBackground"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingTop="16dp"
                android:paddingBottom="16dp"
                android:text="@android:string/cancel"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView android:id="@+id/btn_continue"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/orange_dark_rect_curved"
                android:foreground="?selectableItemBackground"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingTop="16dp"
                android:paddingBottom="16dp"
                android:text="@android:string/ok"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

The code above works fine if a long string is pass through: the image and buttons are fixed, and the middle textview is scrollable; but if only a short string is pass through, there will be a big gap/blank space between the text and the button (due to the layout_height I set to 150dp).

I tried setting the maxHeight of the NestedScrollView to a certain amount, but seems like the maxHeight would be ignore and the height of the textview will expand until fullscreen size. If the string is too long, it might hide the image and button as well because the textview already occupied the whole screen.

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:maxHeight="300dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                android:paddingRight="16dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                tools:text="title" />

            </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Is there anyway I can do, to make the height of the textview to expand dynamically until certain limit?

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1748977/making-textview-scrollable-on-android?rq=2

Comment: @Izak the marked correct answer asked to include android:scrollbars = "vertical", which I already did

Comment: Have you tried constraintLayout with barrier?